# Forcing linebreaks in \url

Tags: line-breaking, urls

> **This question led to a new package:**
> [`xurl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl)

I wish to typeset some relatively long URLs in a piece of text, and when I use `\url{..}`, the resulting text does not respect the margin boundaries that govern the main text body, instead going all the way to the edge of the paper before wrapping around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url}
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling using pdflatex, although I doubt this makes a difference.

Comment: ... but URL shortening (a) makes the destination opaque and (b) adds another indirection layer vulnerable to linkrot.

Comment: I also suggest to consider not solving the problem but use short URLs instead. There are several services like http://goo.gl which will help you here. If the document is printed, then its even easier to transfer the URL to Browser.

Comment: The problem with all the answers, I think, provided to this question is that (when a certain URL is broken across multiple lines) every PDF viewer which I tried will **only highlight that line** of the URL which one is clicking on (and **not the complete** URL), which is confusing. Anybody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

*(converting a previous comment to an answer)*

A quick google search (alas, too quick) reveals one solution. Use the `[hyphens]` option with the `url` package:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Some recommendations also include inserting `\sloppy` in case latex is trying too hard to align things.

Comment: Do you mean that it should look like this: `\usepackage{url}[hyphens]` ?  This does not work for me.

Comment: Did you use both `hyperref` and `url` packages? I got an error saying a package conflict.

Comment: I did use both. has never had a problem for me.

Comment: @xport: `hyperref` loads the `url` package internally. Use `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}` to pass the option to the `url` package when it is loaded by `hyperref`. This avoids any package option clashes.

Comment: @Suresh A minimal usage-example with some [blind text](http://www.ipsum-generator.com/) would be nice.

Comment: @Suresh @Martin Scharrer

Both `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` and `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}` do not seem to work properly. Sure, the url is broken, but this happens at the right boundary of the page instead of at where the right margin begins. How should I solve this?

Comment: If the `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` approach does not work, maybe it's "because you're trying to load the url package with a specific option, but it's being loaded by one of your packages before that with a different set of options. Try loading the url package earlier than the package that requires it. If it's loaded by the document class, try using `\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}` before the document class." http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22526#p76347

Comment: I have just experienced the issue too. On my side, `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` was not working because of BibLaTeX, I had to write that command and load hyperref BEFORE BibLaTeX was loaded, which solved the problem. Gonna edit the answer.

Comment: Actually I made a [new question and self-answered it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237683/), as this wasn't completely related to this one.

Comment: It looks like (as you might expect) this only breaks URLs on hyphens, and doesn't solve eg `https://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/qux/quux/corge`

Comment: Just add e.g.: \def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-} after you loaded hyperref, this will include dashes for a linebreak

Comment: See the newer answer about the xurl package, which automatically resolves the issue.

Comment: This does not solve my "too-long"-issue with `\url{very-long-url}` on the overleaf platform.
@ZachBoyd A link to the resource just here would be helpfull. Thanks

Comment: It seems like `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` is on for default for me, can that be the case? At least I didn't see any difference when using it in front of `\usepackage{hyperref}`. What made a difference was the use of `\sloppy` before the `\url` macro, but now LaTeX complains about an underfull \hbox instead. Ah, what to do :)

Comment: I tried using this solution in the case of using an ```\href``` with a long ```\url``` but I couldn't get pdflatex to compile on overleaf. Any ideas on this?

Comment: it did not work for me but the simple addition of the `xurl` package worked

Answer (score 190):

Herbert Voß created (December 2017) the [package `xurl`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xurl).

This package allows urls to break everywhere, can be compiled simply with `pdflatex`, and has the same options as `url` (indeed, it loads `url` package).

Here an MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt

\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

An example of everywhere breaking url: 
\url{very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url}

Another example of everywhere breaking url: 
\url{very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url}

A third example: 
\url{very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url}

\end{document}
```

Here the output:

[image]

*Update:* since version 0.05 (December 2018) the package author have added support for `biblatex` which has its own url handling.

If you load `xurl` after `biblatex` this is done by default.

If you want to avoid it, load `xurl` before `biblatex` or use the option `nobiblatex`:

```
\usepackage[nobiblatex]{xurl}
```

For more info, see package documentation.

Comment: This does not seem to work in a bib file.

Comment: @carlatex There is already a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134191/line-breaks-of-long-urls-in-biblatex-bibliography) on line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography. Would your answer also work for this question?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin There was an update to the package, now biblatex is supported, see my renewed answer.

Comment: This and the other answers don't work for me! Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/FwBWCLg.png. Source code: https://github.com/jamesray1/holochain-proto/commit/3233caadc075b387051cee1dc73d3d3469f8c8df#diff-9f7a258b295b34d531092c80da297b7fR28. I'll keep trying the others...

Comment: @JamesRay Please post a new question with a minimal example of your code which reproduces your problem.

Comment: @CarLaTeX the PDF is actually failing to compile and refresh, so I can't tell if the changes have been effective yet. I had issues with installing LaTeX due to limited RAM, and rather than setting TMP, TMPDIR, or TEMP env variable to a directory that has enough free space available, I'm waiting for another computer to be built, tested and delivered, as my current one can lag, particularly with VS Code.

Comment: @JamesRay No hurry! However, your comment here is not seen by many people, it is better to post an ordinary question, with a minimal example, explaining which is your problem. I'm sure you'll find someone who can help you.

Comment: It seems not working for `xelatex`. Probably my `hyperref` has conflict?

Comment: @XingangHuang It's better if you ask a question on the main site, I'm not an expert of XeLaTeX, I don't use it, sorry.

Comment: @Kebby When the answer was accepted, `xurl` didn't exist yet :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you for the answer! This package \xurl is great but is it its default behavior to use a different font for the URL than the text (as seen in your screenshot and also my own attempt)? Is it possible to use the same font as the text?

Comment: @nanjun Try with `\urlstyle{same}`. It should use the same font as the text: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87093/101651

Comment: I tried using this solution in the case of using an ```\href``` with a long ```\url``` but I couldn't get pdflatex to compile on overleaf. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @Steven Please ask a new question with a minimal example

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks for  your  reply.  I have  posted my MWE here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689423/using-xurl-package-with-href-and-a-long-url-within-the-longtable-package

Comment: @Steven Is David's answer OK for you?

Comment: @CarLaTeX  Yes! Thank you! My issue is  resolved.

Answer (score 94):

The package `url` defines a command `\def\UrlOrds{\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}%`
which can be added to the default url break characters at which a line can be broken. Below, the line `\g@addto@macro` appends the list of characters defined in `\UrlOrds` to the `\UrlBreaks` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=8cm
\parindent=0pt

\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

foo bar baz \url{very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-very-long-url-}

\end{document}
```

[image: output example]

The same effect could be obtained by using the more usual `\renewcommand` on `\UrlBreaks`, but this would remove the characters that were already defined in `\UrlBreaks`.

**Edit:**
If you load package `etoolbox` you can reduce these 3 lines:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother
```

to this oneliner:

```
\gappto{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
```

Comment: woohoo!  *This* is the only one that worked for me.  The other [similar answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10401/4357) by @xamde blew TeX's capacity.

Comment: Thanks! Works in combination with `sloppypar` wonderfully!

Comment: I wonder why [xurl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xurl) does not have that characters in its `UrlBreaks` definition.

Comment: @koppor Oh, it _has_, at least in version from 2018-12-23 (which is later than your comment).`\UrlBreaks` is just redefined from scratch, but includes the characters that are in `\UrlOrds` in `url.sty`.

Comment: I tried using this solution in the case of using an ```\href``` with a long ```\url``` but I couldn't get pdflatex to compile on overleaf. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 80):

I carefully read the documentation of the `url` package (I'm using PDFLaTeX) and found the following to work quite nice to let LaTeX add line breaks after every normal alphabetic character:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks%  save the current one
  \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
  \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
  \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
  \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
  \do\Y\do\Z}
```

**Update:**
Herbert Voß (who provided the edited version above with all the `\expandafter`s) created a package [`xurl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) which makes it much simpler (see also [answer of CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407368/)). This package takes also care of `biblatex` and does also include numbers and the characters that are defined as `\UrlOrds` in `url`, cf. [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10419/) (which is also from Herbert, though you can not recognize this anymore.)

Comment: None of the previous (higer-rated) suggestions worked for me with a troublesome URL I was dealing with. This option did work. Are there any potential problems with this approach? All I see is that it may not always break at a "visually appealing" part of a URL.

Comment: I used the same solution, but with UrlBigBreaks. Does anybody know whether this has any adverse effects?

Comment: For the record, I was having the url problem while using \url{} inside `enumerate` environment. The other solutions were fine when the \url was inside the text. But this answer is the only one that fixed the url problem inside enumerate. Thank you!

Comment: This solution seems to work better than the others, but I experienced a problem in the limit case when the url ends close to line ending; LaTeX is unable to put the word following the url to a new line and puts such word (or at least the first syllable of it) in the same line, even if it protrudes from right justification, with really bad results.

Comment: I had to cite the following link in a bibliography. http://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/nationalaccounts/uksectoraccounts/datasets/grossandnetcapitalstocksfortotaleconomybyindustryandassetincurrentpricesandchainedvolumemeasures This answer was the only solution.

Comment: It works for me, unlike the other proposed alternatives.

Comment: I tried using this solution in the case of using an ```\href``` with a long ```\url``` but I couldn't get pdflatex to compile on overleaf. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 32):

Using the `sloppypar` environment as in

```
\begin{sloppypar}
  Figure \ref{fig:example_instant_lumi}:
  Public result available from \url{https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/AtlasPublic/LuminosityPublicResults}, version of 16.12.2011.
\end{sloppypar}
```

helps in my case. Without `sloppypar` the `AtlasPublic` part runs over the right margin, with `sloppypar` LaTeX breaks after `view/` and everything's fine.
(Doesn't need the `url` package.)

Comment: I found that `sloppypar` and the `url` package worked well together.

Comment: I have combined the suggestion by @Herbert and yours, and it looks like this  method works for me. But I found one "full stop" notation below the reference entry. Is there any way to eliminate that? Thank you.

Comment: This also works with biber. `\begin{sloppypar}
\printbibliography
\end{sloppypar}`

Answer (score 16):

If it's not necessary for the url to appear verbatim, you could use `\href{url}{text}`. That way you could give the url a human-readable form. If your document is used electronically you just use it as an hyperlink and if the document is printed you could (or should) question the relevance of long (and probably cryptic) url's.

Comment: URLs often appear in bibliographies. For an online resource, they should not be omitted.

Comment: I could have reformatted the text as a bibliography, but in my particular setting this would have been too clunky.

Comment: For some ungainly long URLs one can set up URL-shortened links via tinyurl.com, bit.ly, or other similar sites.  Then the printed link can be the readable short link but the underlying link in the PDF can go to the original URL.

Comment: You can also use \href with the text set to the url, using \texttt, and putting the line breaks in explicitly. You gain flexibility at the price of a little more work.

Comment: Instead of `\texttt` with manual line breaks, you can use the `\path` command from the `url` package, as mentioned in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299/how-to-get-long-texttt-sections-to-break).  This is the only way I was able to get sensible display of URLs in a bibliography on the arXiv.

Comment: I tried using this solution in the case of using an \href with a long \url but I couldn't get pdflatex to compile on overleaf. Any ideas on this?  Here is my MWE using \xurl package:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689423/using-xurl-package-with-href-and-a-long-url-within-the-longtable-package

Answer (score 16):

1. `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` should be ok. If it does not work, then go to (2).
2. `\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}` before `\documentclass`.
3. `\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks%  save the current one
         \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
         \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
         \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
         \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
         \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
         \do\Y\do\Z}`

   It does work, but it is not a good way because it breaks the url address at an arbitrary place, which looks ugly.
4. `\sloppy` sometimes does work, sometimes does not. It is not a thorough solution.

I recommend Solution (1) or (2).

Comment: `\soppy` should be used iin a group only.

Comment: I feel this is more or less a mash-up of other answer already given, can you explain what your approach adds to the answers present.

Comment: @moewe I have surveyed and summarized the answers above.

Comment: Mhhh, yes, I thought that as well. But normally I think this is left to the reader and we prefer not to add answers that don't introduce new approaches.

Comment: @moewe I agree with you in general. But I think it is also important and necessary to tell others which approaches are formal and which are unsuitable. After all, people's time is precious. At the same time, I have troubled with this problem for so long a time that I want to tell the correct answer to you once I find it.

Comment: I think you can show your approval or disapproval of certain solutions by voting and commenting, so those summary answers are of no real use. But then again, some people may like those summary answers. I just wanted to point out that these answers are really unusual here.

Comment: @moewe Yes, you are right. But the only problem is that I have no enough reputations to comment others' answers.

Comment: Ah well, that is the reputation system for you ...

Comment: Upvoting the best answers ensures they are on top and seen first. This is our way of making a summary ;-)

Comment: Your number 2. solution worked for me since I am using the url package and the Tufte Book Class.  I was having the issue of the URL's extending beyond the margin of the page in the margin notes.

Answer (score 9):

You may also want to look at the `breakurl` package.

Comment: this is a package for `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` and not for `pdflatex`

Answer (score 7):

According to the documenation, BigBreaks is the way to go otherwise it breaks at the first character.

```
\def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\/\do-\do:}
```

See: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf
I had the problem that a line break was inserted always after `http:`, even when using `\UrlBreaks`, the documentation clarified that this is the intended behavior.

Comment: I tried using this solution in the case of using an ```\href``` with a long ```\url``` but I couldn't get pdflatex to compile on overleaf. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4):

Not using `\url`, but `\href`, the URL is not visible anyway, so the suggestion in regard to employing tinyurl is relevant as it does avoid the ugliness of the URL in the text.

Much better, I find, to make an appropriate part of the text active, as in `\href{URL}{active in context text}`.

This way, the URL is not visible in the print out either.

Comment: This would be a fine idea if it was never to be printed on paper as a stand-alone work..

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem with `itemize` environment. When a word (or an url) is too long to respect the margin it does not starts a newline. Using `\sloppy` works but is very ugly.

My LaTeX code is generated by *rst2latex.py* and I use *pdflatex* on it.

I found that much better solution on the [latex-community.org forum](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=21170#p70342) :

```
\tolerance 1414
\hbadness 1414
\emergencystretch 1.5em
\hfuzz 0.3pt
\widowpenalty=10000
\vfuzz \hfuzz
\raggedbottom
```

So I add this snippet in my *docutils.tex* and everything is just fine !

Comment: I think it is ok to post this here, but please have a look, if this works for the original problem too.

Comment: I have checked with urls and it works. I can't remember why I was talking about the `abstract` context, maybe my brain was still in another post.

Answer (score 3):

I troubles I had with url breaking in an itemize environment could be solved by adding `\Urlmuskip = 0mu plus 1mu` in the preamble.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I tried using this solution in the case of using an ```\href``` with a long ```\url``` but I couldn't get pdflatex to compile on overleaf. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3):

The top-voted answer did not completely work for me and I really won't use the most ridicule way of requesting a line break for each letter of the alphabet(!) as some answers suggest here. (I'd wonder what happens if you then have a lot of emojis in your URLs or so, which is – theoretically at least – a thing in 2019.)

Instead though, I found this nice solutions, which really seems to force breaking URLs at *any* position:

```
% always break URLs anywhere!
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000} % lower letters
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000} % upper letters
```

Source [is this forum post](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=25143), which actually refers to [this German forum post](https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7008/zeilenumbruche-in-bibliografielinks).

In my testing it worked, and, okay, I admit, I did not test it with emojis.

Answer (score 1):

I used the .bib file with these packages.

```
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{url}
```

And that made the work.

Comment: This answer is already covered by [adl's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5682/95441) ...

Answer (score 1):

I would like to link to the following question here on TeX-SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207712/128658

Followed by `\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu\relax` this does result in URLs that are properly broken over multiple lines without causing any overfull boxes. Plus this does also work for URLs in bibliographys (opposed to @xamde's answer to this question).

If you are doing this sorcery inside a package instead of your actual document you have to encapsulate the counter-changes in a `\AtBeginDocument` as they aren't defined otherwise. It could therefore look something like this:

```
% set special behaviour for hyperlinks in pdfs
\RequirePackage[breaklinks=true, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\g@addto@macro\UrlBreaks
{%
    \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
    \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
    \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\&\do\1\do\2\do\3%
    \do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\0\do\/\do\.%
}
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials
{%
    \do\/{\mbox{\UrlFont/}\hskip 0pt plus 10pt}%
}

\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu\relax

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{1}  %break URL after uppercase character
    \setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{1} %break URL after number
    \setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{1}  %break URL after lowercase character
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works perfect for me both for `bibtex` and `biblatex` is the combination of `sloppypar` that @fuenfundachtzig mentioned with the `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` that proposed by @Suresh.

The next code is used to be able to use both ways (`bibtex` and `biblatex`) to compile your file and works for me in cases of `natbib`s `agsm` style and `biber`s `authoryear`. Actually you don't have to use both ways and the method will work (I think) anyway if you just keep the code of each case (`bibtex` or `biblatex`) [except of the trick of @moewe with the url that solved the problem I had in my post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455698/enabling-double-way-for-bibliography-with-url-both-bibtex-and-biblatex-biber) that will be possibly need to be adjusted according to the `bibtex` style we will use].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% \UseBibLaTex is a variable that if is less than 1 the document 
% will have to compiled with `bibTeX`... else with biber
\def\UseBibLaTeX{1}
% ``url'' package is used in order to make LaTeX to break the urls 
% in places like the bibliography combined with the next (upcoming) 
% command
%\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu minus 5mu


\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myBib.bib}
\else
\usepackage{natbib}
\def\harvardurl#1{{\bfseries URL:}\space\url{#1}}
\fi


\begin{filecontents*}{myBib.bib}
@Article{cite1,
title={One Article with a url that has to break both in bibtex and biblatex},
author={Someone NotMe and Someother Me},
year={2018},
month={10},
url={http://A-long-URL-that-has-to-break-through-lines-and-biber-has-to-ignore-the-url-command},
doi={http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nphys1170}
}
@Article{cite2,
title={One Article with another url that has to break both in bibtex and biblatex},
author={Someone NotMe and Myself Me},
year={2017},
month={10},
url={http://AlongUrlThatHasToBreak.ThroughlinesAndBoth.BiberAndBiblatex.HasToAcceptTheCitation.com},
doi={http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nphys1170}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\title{Double Functionality about Bibliography}
\author{Konstantinos Leledakis}
\date{October 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\nocite{*}
\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
\begin{sloppypar}
\printbibliography
\end{sloppypar}
\else
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{sloppypar}
  \bibliography{myBib}
\end{sloppypar}
\fi

\end{document}
```

Output with **bibtex**:

[image]

Output with **biblatex** (biber):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility to force a linebreak by using a user-defined character inside the url. This is documented in the [url package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) under 5.2.1 Arbitrary character actions:

> You can do arbitrarily complex things with characters by specifying their definition(s) in `\UrlSpecials`. This makes them ‘active’ in math mode (mathcode "8000). The format for setting each special character c is: `\do\c{hdefinitioni}`, but other definitions not following this style can also be included. Here is an example to make `“!”` inside `\url` force a line break instead of being treated verbatim (it uses LATEX’s `\g@addto@macro`):

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\do\!{\newline}}
```

I think there are some downsides like using only ascii characters as the user-defined character (maybe, I'm not sure), and to have the user-defined character in the original url text, of course. I successfully tried the character `|` which I haven't found in any of my urls.

So you can write:

```
\url{https://what-an-example.org/subfolder/view.!php?id=12345}
```

which will give you:

```
https://what-an-example.org/subfolder/view.
php?id=12345
```