# hyperref url breaking

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, urls

References: [Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url)

So, in a plain document with

```
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
You can find this at \url{very-long-url}.
\end{document}
```

the URL will be broken down, e.g. after slashes. When however `\usepackage{hyperref}` is in effect, breaks are inhibited. I tried adding `\usepackage{breakurl}` below hyperref, and while it does break URLs again, the colorful border that hyperref added is now very faint. How could this last issue be remedied?

Comment: are you running latex or pdflatex?

Comment: You can use `\href{http://www.microsoft.com/msdn/csharp/blablabla.aspx}{How to cook}`

Comment: Try \usepackage[breaklinkes]{hyperref}

Comment: Currently the combination of latex - dvips - ps2pdf.

Comment: \href{}{with link text} won't help because the URL is supposed to be visible in the book.

Comment: \usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref} fails to break the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the width on the border. The needed value depends on the  resolution settings of `dvips`. E.g. with `dvips -Ppdf` a value of 100 is okay, without `-Ppdf` you can try 5.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 100}}
\textwidth=3cm
\begin{document}
\url{long/long/long/long/long/long/blub/bla/bla}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\href{<link url>}{<link url again>}
```

Works for my purposes.