# Difference between latex-dvips and pdflatex - resolutions

Tags: pdftex, dvi

The answer to a previous question — [hyperref url breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/hyperref-url-breaking) — has got me puzzled. If you take the example code of the accepted answer and use `pdfborder={0 0 10}` (instead of 100), two things will happen:

- with `latex test.tex && dvips test.dvi && ps2pdf test.ps`, the resulting document will have a border that's "right"
- with `pdflatex test.tex` however, one gets a big blob of the link color, generally cyan (texlive).

Can one say what is causing this? The linked thread mentions a `-Ppdf` option though I am not sure what that entails. Is it perhaps that the link border is a bitmap rather than a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the package `breakurl` calculates the setting of the borderwidth depending to its contents, whereas `pdflatex` passes it as a pdfliteral without any changes into the pdf.

Comment: Very interesting! Should one consider this a bug?