# Manually breaking a long URL (in the bibliography)

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, urls

I have a large bibliography in which a few items are causing underfull hboxes due to a long URL. Answers to similar questions suggest a number of global options for fixing this; e.g.

[Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url?rq=1)

[hyperref url breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/hyperref-url-breaking?rq=1)

[Line breaking of URLs in bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15653/perform-a-line-break-of-an-url-in-bibliography-manually-biblatex-hyperref?rq=1)

However, I don't want a global solution (like applying `\sloppy` or `\raggedright` to the whole bibliography), because all the other bibliography items behave as I want them to.

In most cases, I have been able to resolve the issue by inserting a manual line break at the start of the url entry in the .bib file. However, in one case that isn't working. MWE:

```
\documentclass[natbib]{svmono}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{koepke2009naturalness}
\bibliographystyle{harvard}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

test.bib

```
@article{koepke2009naturalness,
  year={2009},
  title={Naturalness in formal mathematics},
  journal={\\\url{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Naturalness_in_formal_mathematics.pdf}},
  author={Koepke, Peter}
}
```

I've tried inserting `\\` at various points inside the url; it breaks the line, but I still get an underfull hbox. How can I break the url in a way which doesn't cause an underfull hbox?

Edit: http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0 <-- svmono
http://iccle.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2130/trunk/doc/harvard.bst <-- harvard.bst

Comment: Is this a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? `harvard.bst`? `svmono.cls`?

Comment: Normally, the `journal` field should not be for a `\url`

Comment: After adding the missing `,`, it looks good. The underfull box is still there, but I don't think you can avoid that with such long URLs. You have a `tt` font and no space. What should LaTeX do wit that line in your opinion?

Comment: @Guido: where should the url go?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: If I write e.g.
    `\\\url{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/\\Preprints/Naturalness_in_formal_mathematics.pdf`

I would expect the extra manual line break to prevent the underfull box.

Comment: Also: missing `,`?

Comment: Between the `jornal` and the `author` field. With `{\url{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/}\\\url{Preprints/Naturalness_in_formal_mathematics.pdf}}` I don't have an underfull box. Either way, `journal` is for the journal's name, you can use `note` for the URL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Update: This question's OP himself has found a good solution between an extra `\\` and a working hyperref.*

With the help of the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package one can write (the example is changed to an `unpublished` publication because there is, apparently, no journal):

```
@unpublished{koepke2009naturalness,
  year={2009},
  title={Naturalness in formal mathematics},
  note={\\
        \href{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Naturalness_in_formal_mathematics.pdf}
             {\nolinkurl{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/}}
        \\
        \href{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Naturalness_in_formal_mathematics.pdf}
             {\nolinkurl{koepke/Preprints/Naturalness_in_formal_mathematics.pdf}}
       },
  author={Koepke, Peter}
}
```

which gives
[image: Output with two \hrefs]

If only one `\href` is used, like

```
  note={\\
        \href{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Naturalness_in_formal_mathematics.pdf}
             {\nolinkurl{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{koepke/Preprints/Naturalness_in_formal_mathematics.pdf}
             }
       },
```

the link-active area spans the whole first line:
[image: Output with one \href]

## Original answer

An underfull hbox doesn't mean that there's necessarily something wrong. It is merely a warning.

Compare the bibliography entries of the following code.
The one with the extra `\\` doesn't give a warning (but breaks the hyperlink, by the way), the other one does give a warning, but looks the same.

*(The italic setting from the `journal` field did mess up the spacing either way.)*

### Code

```
\documentclass[natbib]{svmono}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{koepke2009naturalness,
  year={2009},
  title={Naturalness in formal mathematics},
  journal={Same Journal Name},
  note={\\\url{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Naturalness_in_}\\\url{formal_mathematics.pdf}},
  author={Koepke, Peter}
}
@article{koepke2009naturalnessa,
  year={2009},
  title={Naturalness in formal mathematics},
  journal={Same Journal Name},
  note={\\\url{http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Naturalness_in_formal_mathematics.pdf}},
  author={Koepke, Peter}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{*}
\bibliographystyle{harvard}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: See below for a way of not breaking the hyperlink.