# Faint pdfborder borders for URL links when using breakurl

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I have been battling to have URLs appear with borders in my manuscript, and after poking around, it appears the problem is the way I am generating my final PDF output. I cycle through `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` to get my final output and for some reason, the resulting document ends up having very faint borders for URLs --I believe my problem is similar to [hyperref url breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/hyperref-url-breaking). Incidentally, my other links (cross-references and DOIs) are not affected.

1. Running pdflatex on minimal example below gives desired result, however, my manuscript can not be processed using pdflatex in its current form; is their a work around for this?
2. I tried fiddling with pdfborder properties, however, this affects my other internal links...
3. An alternative would perhaps be to find a substitution to the breakurl package (I currently use a combination of breakurl& sloppy directive to break long URLs), however, I was unable to find a suitable replacement.

I have added some sample outputs below of different approaches I used to try and resolve this issue.

**Output using hyperref colourlinks**

[image]

**Output using default pdfborder options --pdfborder(0 0 1)**

[image]

**Output using modified pdfborder options --pdfborder(0 0 10)**

[image]

**Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,maxnames=3,natbib=true,urldate=long]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{breakurl_hyperref.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\begin{document}

\sloppy

\title{Issue with breakurl package and hyperref package}

\author{Munthu Wakuda}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

This is a test citation \citep{Wiltshire2011}...

%\sloppy
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**breakurl_hyperref.bib**

```
@report{Wiltshire2011,
title = {{Spatial analysis of archaeological sites in the Western Cape using an integrated digital archive}},
author = {Wiltshire, Nicolas},
institution = {University of Cape Town},
year = {2011},
url = {http://uctscholar.uct.ac.za/R/N8XKKNNCY76DM8GQG33X3C8LCDJ7N6MUKFFKAHMT67HVDJN9TT-03715?func=results-brief},
@note = {Online; accessed February 14, 2013},
urldate = {2012-02-14}
}
```

**Update #1**

Added sample usecases of different possible outputs

Comment: Can it be, that there is *no* three difference between your three examples (at least no difference in line-breaking)? I don't think that the solution will be in customizing pdfborder

Comment: @DL6ER, the issue is not with line breaking but with rather with faint borders around URLs. I know its a trivial thing, but I'd love it if my manuscript was consistent :). Incidentally, I use a combination of `breakurl` package and `\sloppy` to break long URLs.

Comment: Hmm, I just put your example in `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` and the PDF seems ok (http://www.x-linux.de/tex/MWE2.pdf), I'm using a up-to-date version of texlive and Linux. What is your setup? Can you add `\listfiles` to your file to show us, what versions you are using? (For example on my side: biblatex.sty    2013/01/10 v2.5 programmable bibliographies, hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX) -- OH -- found a problem! Will append my answer as I will have to show you some screenshots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link-lineborder-border problem seems to be **PDF-reader-depended**.

---

For example (Adobe Reader 9 on Linux):

[image: Adobe]

Green border ok, but blue missing.

---

And the *same* PDF (Evince 3.4 on Linux):

[image: Evince]

All ok.

---

And again the same PDF (using the new firefox pdf-engine):

[image: Firefox-PDF]

All borders missing.

---

The displayed PDF [can be found here](http://www.x-linux.de/tex/MWE2.pdf).

---

So what reader are you using? I have printed the PDF on all readers and these are the same, as the linkborders are always removed completely.

Comment: you are right! I feel sheepish... I primarily use Acrobat Reader 9 on Ubuntu& didn't bother to check output using other readers. I tried viewing document in Okular& borders are there... Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, haven't known that for sure, just assumed it. So we both got value out of your question :-) +1 for that!