# URL line breaks with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, urls

How do I allow long URLs to have line breaks at any point. This is in the bibliography not the main text. I am trying to save space so don't want extra spaces to be added to make it only break at slashes, for example, as it does by default.  I am using `biblatex`+`biber`.

Comment: do you want to allow a linebreak at _any_ symbol/character?

Comment: Have you already seen [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url) and the answers given there?

Comment: Yes at any symbol/character. I really just want to wrap very crudely to save maximum space.  I don't want it to hyphenate however as that would be confusing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Answers to [the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/4483) linked in domwass's comment mention the package `url`. This package is already loaded by `biblatex`. It is configured with the command `\biburlsetup` defined in `biblatex.def`.

URLs are broken at the set of characters specified in `\UrlBreaks`, `\UrlBigBreaks` and `\UrlSpecials`. `\UrlBigBreaks` will prevent breaks from occurring between repeating characters (e.g. `--` and `::` in the code below). `\UrlSpecials` handles breaks at characters that may not be present in the document font.

Upgrading to the latest version of `biblatex` should solve your problem as `\biburlsetup` was expanded in version `1.4c` to permit breakpoints at many different characters. For reference here is the definition for `\biburlsetup` from version `1.7`:

```
\newcounter{biburlnumpenalty}
\newcounter{biburlucpenalty}
\newcounter{biburllcpenalty}

\newcommand*{\biburlsetup}{%
  \Urlmuskip=0mu plus 3mu\relax
  \mathchardef\UrlBigBreakPenalty=100\relax
  \mathchardef\UrlBreakPenalty=200\relax
  \def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\:\do\-}%
  \def\UrlBreaks{%
    \do\.\do\@\do\/\do\\\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]\do\)\do\}%
    \do\,\do\?\do\'\do\+\do\=\do\#\do\$\do\&\do\*\do\^\do\"}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{biburlnumpenalty}}{0}
    {\def\do##1{\appto\UrlSpecials{\do##1{\mathchar`##1 \penalty\value{biburlnumpenalty}}}}%
     \do\1\do\2\do\3\do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\0}
    {}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{biburlucpenalty}}{0}
    {\def\do##1{\appto\UrlSpecials{\do##1{\mathchar`##1 \penalty\value{biburlucpenalty}}}}%
     \do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J
     \do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T
     \do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}
    {}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{biburllcpenalty}}{0}
    {\def\do##1{\appto\UrlSpecials{\do##1{\mathchar`##1 \penalty\value{biburllcpenalty}}}}%
     \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j
     \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t
     \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z}
    {}%
  \let\do=\noexpand}
```

Unlike versions `1.4c` to `1.6`, this new definition no longer allows breakpoints at numbers, uppercase letters and lowercase letters by default. Breaks at these characters can be permitted by setting the penalty counters to a value between `0` and `10000`, exclusive. For example:

```
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{100}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{100}
```

The penalties can be reset locally using the command `\defcounter` from the `etoolbox` package (also loaded by `biblatex`). For example:

```
\defcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{3000}
\defcounter{biburlucpenalty}{6000}
\defcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
```

To use this new setup with an older version of `biblatex`, just put the code defining `\biburlsetup` and its penalty counters in your preamble and replace `\newcommand` with `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow feel this ought to have been easier :)

Comment: Interesting! Could you explain why you handle digits in this way?

Comment: @Martin The `\UrlSpecials` appears as defined by `biblatex`/Philipp Lehman. I am not sure why myself. If you (or anyone else for that matter) can figure it out, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: That's fine, I was just curious.

Comment: HI, I tried your solution, but `biblatex` won’t break URLs between two letters e.g. `http://www.phidgets.com/docs/Programming_ Resources`should be broken between the two `m` of `Programming` but it doesn’t work … I copied your code ti my preamble and setup `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}`.

Comment: @Tobi Unless you're using a version before 1.7, you only need to reset the break penalties. The code above is just explanatory. To handle the odd overfull box you can [reset the penalties locally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30857/4483).

Comment: Oh … I read your anser again and saw that you posted the default behavior in 1.7, which I’m using. But I don’t get breakpoints in mid words, though … Shall I post a follow-up question?

Comment: @Tobi Sorry - correction: by default breakpoints aren't permitted at letters. You should try setting the biburlucpenalty (uppercase letters) and biburllcpenalty (lowercase letter) penalties. Again you can do this locally or globally.

Comment: Hm … where (and how) do I have to change these values? I tried it via `\biburlsetup` and at my preamble with `\defcounter` and `\setcounter` – nothing happened …

Comment: @Tobi The documentation is your friend. Don't modify `\biburlsetup`. Just add the `\setcounter` commands to your preamble. You can use `\defcounter` to reset the penalties locally. See the post I linked earlier for an example.

Comment: @Audrey Wouldn't it be nice if it had an index?! Thanks for giving me search terms :-).

Answer (score 1):

Even for website references, my Zotero didn't export a `url = ...` line for .bib files, but just `howpublished = {https://...}`. This caused some URLs in the bibliography (I had to use multibib, not bibtex) to cause overful hboxes, and the URLs shoot out of the document without a line break.
Apparently, behind the hood, there was no \url, but (I think?) a \href from the hyperref package, which has different behavior.

Out of the MANY options I tried, I ended up manually replacing the `howpublished = {https://...}` with a `howpublished = {\url{https://...}}` for the broken links. The URLs might look ugly then, this can be fixed with `\urlstyle{rm}` after `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`.