# long URL's containing "-" in bibtex going beyond page

Tags: xetex, bibtex, hyphenation, urls

I have tried [several](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299/how-to-get-long-texttt-sections-to-break) [top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/bad-formatting-using-urls-in-bibtex) answers with no luck. Here is what I have in my preamble(compiling with xelatex and bibtex).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
```

Here is a sample reference in Bibtex

```
@misc{DemandAccounting,
author={Henry Blodget},
title={Demand Media's Q3 revenue and pageview growth looks fine. But the company continues to capitalize its content costs,...},
month={November},
year={2011},
url={http://www.businessinsider.com/demand-medias-q3-revenue-and-pageview-growth-looks-fine-but-the-company-continues-to-capitalize-its-content-costs-2011-11},
publisher={Business Insider},
note={[10/11/2011]}
}
```

[image: Here is the output]

Even pointing out which solution is right for me and closing this questions down would hugely helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package **url** is set up so that, by default, URLs are not broken at hyphens. With the option `hyphens` they will:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
```

If you want this only in selected parts of your document, you can define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\URLhyphenOn{\def\do@url@hyp{\do\-}}
\newcommand\URLhyphenOff{\def\do@url@hyp{}}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble. Then loading `\usepackage{url}` will have break at hyphens inhibited, but from a `\URLhyphenOn` declaration onwards, the URL will be possibly broken at hyphens, until the group or environment in which the declaration is issued ends or a `\URLhyphenOff` declaration appears.