# How to elegantly break long doi field

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, doi

This is a code snippet from my paper.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{baumert62,
  author = {Baumert, Leonard and Golomb, Solomon W. and Hall, Jr, Marshall},
  doi = {10.1090/S0002-9904-1962-10761-7},
  journal = {Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society},
  number = 3,
  pages = {237--238},
  title = {Discovery of an Hadamard Matrix of Order 92},
  volume = 68,
  year = 1962
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

% for back reference in bibliography
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks,pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

% for biblatex with biber
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  citestyle=alphabetic,
  backref=true]{biblatex}

% for DOI field
\usepackage{doi}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
The first missing order of 92 was resolved in 1962 by Baumert, Golomb,
and Hall Jr. \cite{baumert62} who ran computer experiment on Williamson's method.

%%% bibliography
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It generates a bibliography item whose [DOI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) field is too long.

[image]

Naturally, I guess everyone wants to fix it.
I know that I can use the following as explained in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22871/23061) thread.

```
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}  % allow breaks at numbers
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{100}   % allow breaks at uppercase letters
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{100}   % allow breaks at lowercase letters
```

Instead of allowing linebreaks at numbers, lowercase letters and uppercase letters, I'd like to allow linebreaks at special characters such as `/`, `.` and `-`. As I'm dealing with DOI field, I think these are more appropriate places to allow linebreaks rather than ordinary alphanumeric characters. How can I do that?

Comment: it seems to me that breaking a doi should be handled like a url, but i don't know biblatex, so can't be any more specific.

Comment: The ocgcolorlinks option interferes. From the readme of hyperref: "Main disadvantage: Links cannot be broken across lines."

Comment: Use `colorlinks` option instead of `ocgcolorlinks`

Comment: Very different approach: Create a short alias DOI using http://shortdoi.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option `ocgcolorlinks` doesn't allow line breaks in links.

From [`hyperref`'s README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf)

> **Experimental option ‘ocgcolorlinks’**
>
> The idea are colored links, when viewed, but printed without colors.
>
> ...
>
> - Main disadvantage: Links cannot be broken across lines.

In other words, it is almost the same of the option `colorlinks`, but with two differences.

- `colorlinks` allows line breaks in links, while `ocgcolorlinks` doesn't;
- `colorlinks` preserves colors when the document is printed, while `ocgcolorlinks` prints them in black.

So, what can you do to circumvent this?

Use the `colorlinks` option instead of `ocgcolorlinks` and, when you print the document, choose to print it in "black and white".

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{baumert62,
  author = {Baumert, Leonard and Golomb, Solomon W. and Hall, Jr, Marshall},
  doi = {10.1090/S0002-9904-1962-10761-7},
  journal = {Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society},
  number = 3,
  pages = {237--238},
  title = {Discovery of an Hadamard Matrix of Order 92},
  volume = 68,
  year = 1962
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

% for back reference in bibliography
\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

% for biblatex with biber
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  citestyle=alphabetic,
  backref=true]{biblatex}

% for DOI field
\usepackage{doi}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
The first missing order of 92 was resolved in 1962 by Baumert, Golomb,
and Hall Jr. \cite{baumert62} who ran computer experiment on Williamson's method.

%%% bibliography
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness that **`ocgcolorlinks`** (coloured links printing as black) that wrap around linebreaks (and page breaks, if need be) are now possible with the **`ocgx2`** package:

> ```
> \usepackage{hyperref}
> \usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}
> ```

---

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{baumert62,
  author = {Baumert, Leonard and Golomb, Solomon W. and Hall, Jr, Marshall},
  doi = {10.1090/S0002-9904-1962-10761-7},
  journal = {Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society},
  number = 3,
  pages = {237--238},
  title = {Discovery of an Hadamard Matrix of Order 92},
  volume = 68,
  year = 1962
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

% for back reference in bibliography
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% for biblatex with biber
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  citestyle=alphabetic,
  backref=true]{biblatex}

% for DOI field
\usepackage{doi}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
The first missing order of 92 was resolved in 1962 by Baumert, Golomb,
and Hall Jr. \cite{baumert62} who ran computer experiment on Williamson's method.

%%% bibliography
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't know if there's been an update somewhere along the line, but this is not currently working in Acrobat Pro DC (2015). Links continue to print in color even with `\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}`.

Comment: I will have to test this. Thank you for reporting.

Comment: @kyle Could you please tell us the exact version (Help->About)? I am using 2018.009.20050 which works fine.

Comment: The current 2018.011.20038 of Acrobat Reader works smoothly too.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (2015.006.30417). The release is I guess a few years old; I haven't upgraded since Reader Pro (with editing functionality) is an institutional purchase.

Comment: Phew, fortunately nothing bad happend :-) I can only run tests on Reader. No access to pro.

Comment: Fair enough! It seems pretty strange to me that regular Reader has "better" functionality than Pro does (I even tested actually printing to see if it was just a render issue).

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://shortdoi.org to create a short persistent alias for the DOI, as @matth mentioned. These shortened DOIs have several advantages over the canonical DOI:

1. They are short enough so that line breaking is not necessary.
2. They are easy to copy from paper. A long DOI is almost useless if you only have a paper copy of an article (it's easier to just search for the title/authors).
3. They are more aesthetically pleasing, which means less resistance from publishers and coauthors.

I wrote a script that will process an existing BibTeX file and replace all the DOI names with shortened DOIs:
https://github.com/mosco/bibtex-shorten-doi

A word of caution:
unfortunately short DOIs are not considered proper DOIs and cannot be used for manual lookup on any site other than doi.org, such as CrossRef, Sci-Hub, etc. So at the moment, I do not recommend automatic conversion of all the DOIs in your bibliography.