# How can I break URLs with long unbreakable sections in it using LaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, line-breaking, urls, sharelatex

I would like to know how to break URLs which contains long unbreakable sections in my bibliography using Sharelatex.

That's the code I use to load my bibliography file

```
\usepackage[sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\nocite{*}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=black,
}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

...

\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Bibliografia Completa}
]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,title={Solo articoli}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=book,title={Solo libri}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=misc,title={Solo videografia}]

\end{document}
```

but when I load the bibliography the URLs that have too long unbreakable sections to fit in the page, like that one

> PLoaVOjvkzQtyjhV55wZcdicAz5KexgKvm

, are not automatically broken, forcing me to use the `\\` command.
How can I avoid that and still maintaining a fully justified bibliography and correctly broken URLs?

Albeit the use of the `hyperref` package, I'm not using the `\url{}` command in the bibliography to make the URLs clickable, but they still are.
My bibliography preset looks like this:

```
@misc{,
    author    = "",
    title     = "",
    howpublished = "",
    year      = "",
    url       = "",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would help you could add the actual example you have problems with, so we can check that our solutions actually work for you? While you are at it, please consider making your code snippets a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). The intent of your question is fairly clear even without an MWE, but an MWE makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing and people trying to help you don't need to start from scratch. ...

Comment: ...  It shows that you care about the people trying to help you by not letting them waste their time reproducing what you already have and what is available to you at the stroke of a few buttons and mouse clicks.

Comment: maybe the https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl package can help

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried to load the xurl package in the preamble but, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Change the counters/penalties `biburlnumpenalty`, `biburllcpenalty`, `biburlucpenalty`. See the documentation of biblatex and various questions here.

Comment: Thanks, it worked by adding \setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100} 
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{100} 
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{100} to the preamble.

Comment: So is this a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22854/35864?

Comment: (Un)fortunately yes, but I didn't find that answer in the first place despite having made researches for an hour (maybe because I'm new here and still have to learn how this all works), I think this question can now be closed though. Thank you all for your help.