# Bibliography is out of the border

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking

I have one reference with long url. It goes from abroad. The bibliography style is IEEEtran.

[image]

This is the code for it

```
\bibliographystyle{./IEEEtran}
\bibliography{./IEEEabrv,./IEEEexample}

...

@electronic{n5,
  author        = "A. Terekhov and V. Onosovski",
  title         = "Ubiq Mobile Platform for Mobile Development",
  url       = {http://www.math.spbu.ru/user/ant/all\_articles/076\_Terekhov\_Onos\_PlatformaUbiq.pdf},
}
```

How can I make tex move the last part of this reference to the next line?

This is my used tex distribution:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.10.14) 11 MAY 2019 08:22
```

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Off-topic: It looks like you edited the URL string, changing all instances of  `_` to `\_`. Don't do this: If you end up using the `hyperref` as well, the resulting hyperlinks will point to an invalid address.

Comment: Mico, I use IEEEtran style

Comment: You could try \emergencystretch 3em immediately before \bibliography.

Comment: Try with this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22854/url-line-breaks-with-biblatex

Comment: Ross, \emergencystretch 3em doesn't help at all

Comment: Edoardo, I used that snippet. But it doesn't help me too

Comment: Your used tex distribution is very old (2015). Update your system.