# Modifying reference style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm preparing a document with references that should be set out as follows:

http://www.i-cite.bham.ac.uk/harvard_reference_list.shtml
http://www.i-cite.bham.ac.uk/harvard_citing.shtml

The code I have so far is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
As \citet{test2012} says.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{V1.bib}
\end{document}
```

with a .bib that looks like:

```
@article{test2012,
author  = "Surname, forename",
title   = "Title",
year    = "2012",
journal = "Journal",
volume  = "Volume 1",
number  = "4",
pages   = "342--351" 
}
```

How might I go about modifying this so it fits the way I need the references laid out?

Comment: Regarding the `volume` field: That line should probably read `volume = "1"` rather than `volume = "Volume 1"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

gives you something very similar to your example, except that the year is not in parentheses in the bibliography.

If you want citations in your text to have the date in parentheses, do

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

For more Natbib options see http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php

Comment: Thanks mjrussell, I think I can use this for now. I don't suppose you know how to stop the url={} in a .bib from overfilling the column in a multicols environment by any chance?

Comment: @Andy that is another question and you should ask it as such, as long as it has not been asked before (check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3034/5872) for example)

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure how to do that, but as henrique said, it should probably be a separate question. Also, please consider 'accepting' my answer if it does in fact answer your question :)