# Too long hyperlink can not fit on page

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable

I have a problem with a too long hyperlink.

This reference is one word, but it is too long and doesn't set the text width, so some part is pushed beyond the margin:

```
\hyperlink{label}{IS_TOO_LONG_WORD_WITHOUT_ANY_SEPARATORS...}
```

How to pledge hyperlink to break on a new line (similarly as when LaTeX breaks words across lines)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: It's hard to know how to answer your question without more context.  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Forcing linebreaks in \url](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url)

Answer (score 10):

### Hyperref driver with `breaklinks` support

Then TeX couldn't find break points and the question is not related to `hyperref`.
Solution: Insert break points, e.g. `\-`, `\discretionary`, `\hyphenation`, `\penalty`, …

### Hyperref driver without `breaklinks` support

From the README:

> ### Wrapped/broken link support
>
> Only few drivers support automatically wrapped/broken links, e.g. pdftex, dvipdfm, hypertex. Other drivers
>   lack this feature, e.g. dvips, dvipsone.
>
> Workarounds:
>
> - For long section or caption titles in the table of contents   or list of figures/tables option `linktocpage` can be used.   Then the
>     page number will be a link, and the overlong section   title is not
>     forced into an one line link with overvull `\hbox`   warning.
> - `\url`s are caught by package `breakurl`.
> - The option `breaklinks` is intended for internal use. But it   can be used to force link wrapping, e.g. when printing a   document.
>     However, when such a document is converted to PDF   and viewed with a
>     PDF viewer, the active link area will be   misplaced.
>
>   Another limitation: some penalties are "optimized" by TeX,   thus there are missing break points, especially within   `\url`. (See
>     thread "`hyperref.sty`, `breaklinks` and `url.sty` 3.2"   in
>     comp.text.tex 2005-09).

Also manual broken links are possible:

```
\hyperlink{label}{FIRST_PART}%
\hyperlink{label}{NEXT_PART}%
\hyperlink{label}{LAST_PART}
```