# Page header becomes part of link when an \autoref hyperlink spans pages

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I am using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows. I am using, among other packages, `hyperref` in my MASc thesis and I just noticed something strange. I have an `\autoref` to a table in a paragraph and the link spans pages. That is, the whole link is "Table 4.1", but "Ta-" is at the bottom of page 39 while "ble 4.1" is at the top of page 40.

When this happens, the page header for page 40 (e.g. "Chapter 4.  Blah blah blah      40") has a `hyperref` box around it and links to table 4.1, as do each of "Ta-" and "ble 4.1".

Is this a known bug? I have done some quick searching on Google and on here but haven't come up with anything. I apologize that I don't have a minimum working example for you at the moment, I am trying to submit it this morning. If I have time I will add a MWE this evening.

Comment: you might try putting the ref into an `\mbox` so that it doesn't break.  even a forced line break before the ref would probably not do too much other damage, although the line that now begins "Ta-" may be stretched.  this sounds like a bug (though i'm not sure where), so an example, even a heavily contrived one, would be really useful.  oh, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: As an alternative to the solution proposed by @barbarabeeton you could just rephrase your text a bit in the vicinity of the page break to make TeX break the page at another point in the text.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77853/too-long-hyperlink-can-not-fit-on-page

Answer (score 8):

It is a known limitation, from `README` of `hyperref`:

> ```
> Links across pages
> ------------------
>   In general they have problems:
>   * Some driver doesn't support them at all (see above).
>   * The driver allows it, but the link result might include
>     the footer and/or header, or an error message can
>     occur sometimes.
> ```

As workaround the link should not break across pages. `\mbox` (see Barbara Beeton's comment) can help, but the stretchability of the space inside gets lost as side effect of the boxing.