# different font while using url

Tags: fonts, biblatex, urls

I'm having troubles while using the url command in my bibliography.

I mean:

```
1)
\bibitem{[8]}
{\url{http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246989/Web20Application20Security20Statistics\#Tableofcontent}}

2)
\bibitem{[5]}
Justin~Clarke ``SQL Injection Attacks and Defense'', Syngress Publishing, Inc.2009
```

Unfortunately font 1) is different from 2).

What should I do in oder to get the same font for both items?

I'd like the font used in 1)

to be identical to the one displayed in 2)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 22):

```
\urlstyle{rm}
```

or

```
\urlstyle{same}
```

(See Roey Angel's comment).

The [documentation of package `url`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf) says:

> Style:
>   You can switch the style of printing using `\urlstyle{tt}`, where `tt`
>   can be any defined style.  The pre-defined styles are `tt`, `rm`, `sf`,
>   and `same` which all allow the same linebreaks but different fonts –
>   the first three select a specific font and the `same` style uses the
>   current text font.  You can define your own styles with different fonts
>   and/or line-breaking by following the explanations below.  The `\url`
>   command follows whatever the currently-set style dictates.

Comment: I would suggest `\usrlstyle{same}` which would make the package use the same font as in the rest of the document. The package default it your typewriter font, if I'm not mistaken.