# Why is the doi in biblatex a different font?

Tags: biblatex, typewriter, doi

I am using `biblatex-chicago` (with `\autocite`) and a standard BibTeX file. For some reason, the DOI in my references is in a different font from the rest of the entry. Is this normal?

Comment: Use `\urlstyle{same}` to make the fonts the same. This post is related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87091.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is. The `DOI` is an identifier similar to an `URL` that will likely be transferred from the printed document by typing it into some search field.

As in a `URL` it is important to have clearly distinguishable letters as one can in many cases not distinguish between some characters from the context (compare for example the minor "L" and the capital "i" that look the same in many fonts). Typing the wrong character will in most cases lead to a wrong or not existing document. Therefore the `DOI` is, similar to a `URL`, printed in a typewriter like font, where the letters are clearly distinguishable.

Comment: @DavidRowthorn If you like my answer and if it answers your question you can click on the check mark left of it to mark it as answered. You can also click on the up-pointing pen to vote the answer up if you like it. This will show other users that it is a good answer and solves the question. Also the reputation system is mainly based on those vote.