# How to adjust \UrlFont according to its placement (footnote vs. bibliography)?

Tags: biblatex, urls

In my previous post [I learned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151110/how-to-fix-the-url-and-doi-font-say-make-it-smaller) how to make the URL and DOI font smaller. However there is an issue with the URL font size in footnotes specifically, because the font size is already smaller there. When using `\small`, the URL font is in fact bigger than the `\footnotesize` text. What's the right way to address this, considering I use full citations in footnotes, which are reported in the final bibliography with a normal font size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Donald Arseneau's [`relsize`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package allows for font size changes depending on the size of surrounding text.

`\smaller` prints text smaller than the surrounding text, so we just have to use

```
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\smaller}
```

---

A more complicated solution is to use `biblatex` to detect whether we're in a footnote and use

```
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\iffootnote{\scriptsize\rm}{\small\rm}}
```

Here, the font size is `\scriptsize` (one size smaller than `\footnotesize`) in footnotes and `\small` otherwise.

One can use this method to colour the links in the footnote differently from the rest of the text `\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\iffootnote{\color{red}\scriptsize\rm}{\color{blue}\small\rm}}`, for example

But why would you want to do this if you can use the `relsize` package?

---

The mWE (based on the previous question)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\smaller}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  url = {en ligne},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  url = {online},
}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mkbiblege}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  <#1>
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space{\mkbiblege{\url{#1}}}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum.\footcite{markey,kastenholz}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]