# How to get DOI in bibliography, but not in footnotes?

Tags: biblatex

I am using the OSCOLA `biblatex` package. I use footnotes. All my cited articles appear in a bibliography at the end. When I add DOI numbers to my bib-entries, they also appear in footnotes. However, I don't want them to show up in footnotes, but only in the bibliography. I've tried `doi=false`, but then the DOI number is completely suppressed. Any ideas? I am a newcomer to Latex, so I don't know which other info to provide.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]
\usepackage[style=oscola, doi=true, indexing=cite, citereset=chapter, ibidstyle=uc, backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}


 @article{sarooshi96,
author = {Sarooshi, D},
title = {The Legal Framework Governing United Nations Subsidiary Organs},
journal = {BYBIL},
volume = {67},
pages = {413},
year = {1996},
doi = {10.1093/bybil/67.1.413},}

\begin{document}

 Test test test\footcite[417]{sarooshi96}

\printbibliography[title={Articles}, type=article, heading=mysubbibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Let me know if information is missing. It shows like this in my real document: The DOI should be either deleted in the footnote or should be after the pinpoint of page 416.
[image]

This is how it's shown in the bibliography which is how I want it:
[image]

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Is that enough info?

Comment: Can you please make the code fragments compilable? There is no documentclass given and something like `\addbibresource` is missing. You can use the `filecontents` package to create a .bib file for your document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could it be that this `oscola` style is not compatible with the current version of `biblatex`?

At least I cannot compile your example. But in principle you can test if your are inside a footnote with `\iffootnote`, so maybe the following works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[style=oscola, doi=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{sarooshi96,
author = {Sarooshi, D},
title = {The Legal Framework Governing United Nations Subsidiary Organs},
journal = {BYBIL},
volume = {67},
pages = {413},
year = {1996},
doi = {10.1093/bybil/67.1.413},}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\iffootnote}}{}{\printfield{doi}}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\iftoggle{bbx:url}}
               or test {\ifentrytype{online}}}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}   


\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

 Test test test\footcite[417]{sarooshi96}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sam! That works (if I put it in the real tex-document - I dont know why the minimum example wasn't compilable). One last question: where do you make changes if you wanna change the format of the doi in the bibliography, ie that "doi" is in small capps and to add a dot after the page pinpoint so to show like that: "67 BYBIL 413. doi: 1234567890." ? Again, thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: @Felix see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151110/how-to-fix-the-url-and-doi-font-say-make-it-smaller for the url format

Comment: @Felix The point after the pages, probably some `\renewbibmacro` thing, but without compilable code hard to test.