# same font throughout bibliography

Tags: fonts, biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, typefaces

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\urlstyle{same}
\addbibresource{testbibfont.bib}
\begin{document}
See \cite{aauu:2012kp}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where `testbibfont.bib` is

```
@article{aauu:2012kp,
      author         = "aauutt",
      title          = "{The algorithm}",
      journal        = "Journal",
      volume         = "7",
      year           = "2012",
      pages          = "T10003",
      doi            = "10.1089/1749-0221/7/11/T10003",
      eprint         = "1204.2201",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "data-an",
      reportNumber   = "BBB-12"
}
```

I already align the font of DOI with the rest of the text with `\urlstyle{same}` ([different font while using url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87091/different-font-while-using-url?answertab=active#tab-top)). That would be sufficient were it not for `primaryClass` which uses a different font:

[image]

How to have the font of main text everywhere in bibliography?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed the arXiv `eprint` field format is pretty much the only place where `biblatex` has an explicit `\texttt` instead of `\nolinkurl`/`\url` which are governed by `\urlstyle`.

You have to modify the format a bit to remove the `\tetxttt`

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
  arXiv\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
       \nolinkurl{#1}%
       \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
         {}
         {\addspace\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}%
     \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
       {}
       {\addspace\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}
\makeatother
```

The original definition can be found in [`biblatex.def`, ll. 471-482](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L471-L482).

[image: Output without typewriter/monospace font.]