# How to make all font type same in my Bibliography?

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, citing

I am not sure is there a setting to make all the font style the same especially for my `URL Link` in my Bibliograph

I am not sure how can I post my who MWE which is quite a large file.

[image]

Below is the code:

```
 \pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\doublespacing
```

Is there a way to force all font style the same in my Bibliography?

Comment: Probably adding `\urlstyle{same}` to your preamble will be enough.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87091/different-font-while-using-url

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks. Brillant! It works well.