# Bad formatting of Bibliography

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, bibtex, urls, ragged2e

I tried two ways to format a bibliography with lots of URL's:

1. Without 'RaggedRight'
2. With 'RaggedRight'

In the first case, there are wide spaces between words in some items, that a really not acceptable. In the second case, the whole bibliography looks rather ugly for my taste.

So I'm looking for a third way, without 'RaggedRight' and without the spaces between words. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt, DIV=13, german, a4paper, table]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\sloppy        

\begin{document} 
\part{Part 1}
\label{part:part-1}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chap:chapter-1}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:section-1}


Here I cite two publications: first \cite{toll2009leibnitzMonaden},
then \cite{duarte2011jobsTrends}. 


% \begin{RaggedRight}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{literatur/literatur}
% \end{RaggedRight}

\end{document}
```

using the following .bib file:

```
@Misc{duarte2011jobsTrends,
  author =   {Duarte, Gustavo},
  title =    {{Programming Language Jobs and Trends}},
  howpublished =
                  {\url{http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/programming-language-jobs-and-trends}},
  year =     2011,
  note =     {[Online; accessed 25-July-2011]}
}

@Misc{toll2009leibnitzMonaden,
  author =   {Toll, Andreas},
  title =    {{Leibniz' Philosophie der Monaden}},
  howpublished =
                  {\url{http://www.suite101.de/content/leibnitz-philosophie-der-monaden-a58452}},
  year =     2009,
  note =     {[Online; accessed 04-August-2011]}
}
```

Comment: You have a tough setup the text contains large "chunks" of characters that can't be broken up, you use a 14pt font size, and the measure (line width) is quite narrow. What is the actual line width you're working with? If you were to work with 1"-wide margins and a `\small` font size directive for the bibliography, you'd find that -- at least for the two entries you show -- both fully-justified and RaggedRight text may look fairly good. Incidentally, don't use the `\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}` directive; use `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` instead.

Comment: `breakurl` doesn't work with `pdflatex`. You getting considerably better results with `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` as suggested by Mico.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/15925 .

Comment: Ok, thanks, after playing around with the different options I decided to not use RaggedRight, since \usepackage[hyphens]{url} actually does a better job in avoiding the big gaps between words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between `\RaggedRight` and `\raggedright`. Have you tried (and disliked) both?

I must be honest and say, that I do not quite see what you mean by it "looks ugly" from this example. Maybe you could give a more detailed description of what exactly it is that bothers you.

Alternatively you could also take a look at this package that is specifically designed to handle URLs in the bibliography: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst It has a `alphaurl.bst`, that may do a formatting to your liking. The disadvantage would be that you would need to modify your bibliography to the new tags (`URL` and `Lastchecked`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but \usepackage[hyphens]{url} did a good enough job to avoid modifying the bibliography, so I did not use urlbst.