# space between words in references, using ACM-Reference-Format style, sigconf

Tags: bibtex, acm

Please can someone help me to reduce the spaces between words on the references. I saw many solution on internet but none worked for me.
Sorry for the bad format  of the question, it is the first time I make a question.

Edited:Tried to add below MWEB.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% I have separated file biblo.bib 
%In these two(and some other references) there are appearing spaces between words and some links are going beyond the corner
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Manual{ref13,
    title  = {Germany energy giant RWE launches Ethereum based chargin stations},
    author = {TrustNodes}, 
    note   = {\url{http://www.trustnodes.com/2017/04/29/germanys-energy-giant-launches-100s-ethereum-based-electric-cars-charging-stations}}
}

@Manual{ref27,
    title = {Venezuela is cracking down on bitcoin fever},
    author= {BusinessInsider},    
    year  = {2017},
    note  = {\url{http://uk.businessinsider.com/venezuela-bitcoin-use-popularity-restrictions-and-crackdown-2017-3?r=US\&IR=T}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\input{body}
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{jobname}
\nocite{ref27}%
\nocite{ref13}%In fact I have cited into body.txt where I have the content of the paper
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89751/bad-formatting-of-bibliography

Comment: Similar, but probably not an exact duplicate of the linked question. OP's `documentclass` and respective options appear to imply some peculiarities.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
 \usepackage[hyphens]{url}
```

It may helps in your problem

Here is a MWE without the above line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{biblo.bib}
@Manual{ref1,
  title    =     {Bitcoin: A Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System},
  author   = {Nakamoto Satoshi},
  year     = {2008},
  note     =     {\url{https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf}},
}

@Manual{ref13,
    title  = {Germany energy giant RWE launches Ethereum based chargin stations},
    author = {TrustNodes}, 
    note   =     {\url{http://www.trustnodes.com/2017/04/29/germanys-energy-giant-launches-100s-ethereum-based-electric-cars-charging-stations}}
}
\end{filecontents}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{test}
\cite{ref1}

and

\cite{ref13}


\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{biblo}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

If I comment out that line, I have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the `hyphens` option of the `url` package clashes with your setting, but you can try the following (credit to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102697/105447):

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Manual{ref13,
    title  = {Germany energy giant RWE launches Ethereum based chargin stations},
    author = {TrustNodes}, 
    note   = {\url{http://www.trustnodes.com/2017/04/29/germanys-energy-giant-launches-100s-ethereum-based-electric-cars-charging-stations}}
}

@Manual{ref27,
    title = {Venezuela is cracking down on bitcoin fever},
    author= {BusinessInsider},    
    year  = {2017},
    note  = {\url{http://uk.businessinsider.com/venezuela-bitcoin-use-popularity-restrictions-and-crackdown-2017-3?r=US\&IR=T}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\nocite{ref27}%
\nocite{ref13}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I must add that someone might very well come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is the following:

- add `\documentclass[sigconf, hyphens]{acmart}` instead of `\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}`, since the url package is already included by template, but you can provide the *hyphens* parameter to the \documentclass, which will be passed to the url package (not sure though how this works internally) and it should work.

Comment: This works because `acmart` loads `hyperref` and `hyperref` loads `url`. When you pass an option (in this case `hyphens`) to `\documentclass`, all packages loaded will know of this option and will use it if appropriate ([reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/485682/134574)). So this does the same as koleygr's answer, wit fewer keystrokes :-)