# Differences between \documentclass[spanish]{article} and \usepackage[spanish]{babel}

Tags: babel, class-options

This is my second post in latex-SE. Here is a very (I think) basic question, but I could'nt find a precise answer yet:

What exactly does the command `\documentclass[spanish]{article}` and what sets it apart from the command: `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`?

Thanks, in advance, for your kindly answer(s).

Comment: When you pass the option to `\usepackage`, that option will affect that specific package only. Other packages that happen to have an option named `spanish` will not (generally) know that you used that option. If you pass the option to `\documentclass` then the option becomes global and all packages that happen to have an `spanish` option will use it. (I'm pretty sure there is a duplicate of this, I just can't find it now)

Comment: Hello  Phelype Oleinik. Now it is clear for me,  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the option to `\usepackage`, that option will affect that specific package only. Other packages that happen to have an option named `spanish` will not (generally) know that you used that option. If you pass the option to `\documentclass` then the option becomes global and all packages that happen to have an `spanish` option will use it.

The relevant bits of documentation can be found, in [“LaTeX2ε for authors”](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/usrguide.pdf), section **2.2 Class and package options**:

> [image]

and in the [“The LaTeX2ε Sources”](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf), section **67 user interface** (note especially the last paragraph):

> [image]

Comment: Now it's _very_ clear. I compose my documents using LyX, in spanish language. Now I see why `LyX` puts the line `\documentclass[spanish]{article}` at the very beginning of any exported file. Thanks, a lot, Phelype!

Comment: @Patone You're welcome :-)