# Line breaks and the URL package

Tags: line-breaking, urls, dvi-mode

Long URLs need to be broken at the end of a line. [Here's a topic about that.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url/10401) That topic suggests adding the hyphens option to the URL package, and also to define

```
\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}
```

I've done both, but it still doesn't work. Below is a copy of an example. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}

\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[small,font=it]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}

\begin{document}

This is a test. Kurzweil says technology increases exponentially (\url{http://www.kurzweilai.net/the-law-of-accelerating-returns}).

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** I am using latex and then dvipdf to compile.

Comment: It works fine for me without any special considerations.  It splits at `http://|split|www.-----`

Comment: I use latex and then dvipdf if that matters. I cannot understand why it would work for some and not others.

Comment: oh goodness.  yep, that's it.  ... *that is weird*.  I would put your build pattern in the question, since it seems to be relevant.

Comment: dvips/ps2pdf produces the same result.  It may be that pdflatex is the only one that works here.  The DVI also is messed up; so there has got to be some rationale for this behavior (although it looks like a lucky bug in pdflatex).

Comment: Yes, I got it to work with pdflatex. Thank you very much, if you want to post that as a solution I could accept it. Odd though, I only ever noticed the difference when dealing with images before.

Comment: Very odd indeed.

Comment: Isn't this what the package `breakurl` (load it after `hyperref`) solves?  It works find in your test file, even with `dvipdf`: in both `.dvi` and `.pdf` the link is broken after the 'www.'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing the problem in the first place, but `pdflatex` gives the desired output without any fuss whatsoever.  The issue seems to be reproducible only with a `latex dvipdf` or `latex dvips ps2pdf` build pattern.  The DVI produced by `latex` exhibits this issue (viewed under `xdvi`), so it is no wonder that the trailing build processes fail.

A better solution must yet exist, but using `pdflatex` in the first place circumvents the issue for the most part.  (The hyphenation patterns leave much to be desired.)

`latex` output:  (DVI screenshot viewed under `xvdi`; the red line is the page edge)
[image: latex output]

`pdflatex` output:
[image: pdflatex output]

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution, that might be of interest to all the ones having problems with displaying long URLs in LaTeX:
I had a little chat with Vilar (the maintainer of the `breakurl`-package) and he was able to extend the breaking possibilities of his package they way I suggested.

Therefore the new option `anythingbreaks` in the newest version does the links look good as they keep in range of the textborder.

---

See for yourself:

Completely without:

[image: without]

---

Standard behavior:

[image: breakurl]

---

Anythingbreaks:

[image: option anythingbreaks]

Look also at my question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108001/28200

Answer (score 1):

One can fix this by loading the package `breakurl` after `hyperref` (which should also be loaded later in the preamble):

```
...
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\d\o\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}
\usepackage{breakurl}
```

With this addition, on the given test file, the `.dvi` breaks right after `http://www.`, as it does in the `.pdf` made with `dvipdf`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an automated solution, but I currently use a macro that manually breaks URLs up:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\brokenurl}[2]{\href{#1#2}{\texttt{#1}}\par\nopagebreak\href{#1#2}{\texttt{#2}}}
\newcommand*{\brokenurlwithoutpar}[2]{\href{#1#2}{\texttt{#1}}\\*\href{#1#2}{\texttt{#2}}}

\begin{document}

Kurzweil says technology increases exponentially (\url{http://www.kurzweilai.net/the-law-of-accelerating-returns}).

Kurzweil says technology increases exponentially (\brokenurl{http://www.kurzweilai}{.net/the-law-of-accelerating-returns}).

Kurzweil says technology increases exponentially (\brokenurlwithoutpar{http://www.kurzweilai}{.net/the-law-of-accelerating-returns}).

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This "solution" of mine is an occasional **last resort**, when nothing else helps. Yes, it's obvious, it's not deep, and it doesn't use any tricks - but every so often it's the only thing that seems to work. Note the difference between `\brokenurl` (with `\par\nopagebreak`) and `\brokenurlwithoutpar` (with `\\*`); when you set something like `\parindent0pt`, the two behave nearly the same (it's in fact hard to construct an example where their right-alignment behavior is different). Now it occurs to me that defining the macro with `\par\nopagebreak\noindent` instead of just `\par\nopagebreak` would avoid any need for `\parindent0pt`, but then, depending on the context you're in (say, a bibliography), you might intentionally want an indented continuation of a broken URL, to make it clear that the item is a continuation of the previous line; it depends very much on the formatting and style.

Note that my method works smoothly even if you break within words in arbitrary places (eg, `\brokenurl{http://www.kurz}{weilai.net/...}`).