# Biblatex: URL-breaking not working in DVI-mode

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, urls, dvips

I'm preparing my bibliography and noticed that biblatex-printbibliography produces `Overfull \hbox` several times.

Examples (gray lines indicates text margins, red line is the physical page margin):

[image: First Example]

[image: Third example]

[image: Second Example]

**Why is hyperref line-breaking not working as expected using `pdflatex` or even `latex -> dvipdfm` *BUT* not using `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`?**

Also it would be great if someone could point out how I can raise the indentation of the second (and following) lines, as this might look better.

edit: Customized question, as the answer given by lockstep solved the third problem. The second problem seems to be identical to the first.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ps2pdf]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[ps2pdf,breaklinks=true]{hyperref} %This doesn't change anything.
%\usepackage{breakurl} %That makes no difference either.

\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,showframe]{geometry} %show text margins

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber,maxnames=4,minnames=3,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-issue}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=article,prefixnumbers={A-}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=book,prefixnumbers={B-}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=online]

\end{document}
```

And the bib-file:

```
@online{GLS:datasheet,
    title         = "GLS Datasheet",
    organization  = "Optoelectronics Research Centre",
    howpublished ="Website",
    date = "2004-09",
    urldate="2013-07-01",
    url ="http://www.southampton.XXXX",
    address       = "Southampton, United Kingdom"
}
@book {Lifante:Fundamentals,
    title = "Integrated Photonics: Fundamentals",
    author = "Lifante, Ginés",
    publisher = "J.Wiley",
    address = "Chichester",
    year = "2003",
    type = "text",
    isbn = "9780470848685"
}
@article{Labadie:First_fringes,
    author = {Labadie, L. and Mart\'{\i}n, G. and Anheier, N. C. and Arezki, B. and Qiao, H. A. and Bernacki, B. and Kern, P.},
    title = {First fringes with an integrated-optics beam combiner at 10},
    DOI= "10.1051/0004-6361/201116727",
    journal = {A\&A},
    year = 2011,
    volume = 531,
    pages = "A48"
}
```

---

P.S.: I noticed that the visiting-date of the GLS-datasheet is wrong ;-)

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a complete MWE.

Comment: I removed the [tag:boxes] tag because it isn't used for questions about "bad" linebreaks.

Comment: I haven't put that flag in..hmm... Added MWE. Problem for the URL disappeared somehow, don't know why.

Comment: Rather than adding links, please include the `.tex` and `.bib` files directly in the question (as code samples).

Comment: The first and the second problem can be avoided when removing `hyperref` (that is not a good solution). Although the third problem (Wiley leaking out of the margin) still remains.

Comment: I just noted, that the visible DOI-Link is not the actual one, but just a label, and that seems to be the problem: The label of a URL will not break just as any url would do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answer to my own question as I finally found a solution, that might be of interest to all the ones having problems with displaying long URLs in LaTeX and also to show you the effect:
I had a little chat with Vilar (the maintainer of the `breakurl`-package) and he was able to extend the breaking possibilities of his package they way I suggested.

Therefore the new option `anythingbreaks` in the newest version does the links look good as they keep in range of the textborder.

---

See for yourself:

Completely without:

[image: without]

---

Standard behavior:

[image: breakurl]

---

Anythingbreaks:

[image: option anythingbreaks]

---

@lockstep: Thanks for your solution regarding the third problem. Really have missed the `~`.

Answer (score 4):

The first and second problem *could* be solved by removing the `ps2pdf` package option and running your example in PDF mode (see my picture) -- but that may not be an option for you. With regard to the third problem, an unbreakable space is missing in `J.Wiley` -- with `J.~Wiley`, a hyphen will be added after the `i` and the line break becomes acceptable.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber,maxnames=4,minnames=3,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{GLS:datasheet,
    title         = "GLS Datasheet",
    organization  = "Optoelectronics Research Centre",
    howpublished ="Website",
    date = "2004-09",
    urldate="2013-07-01",
    url ="http://www.southampton.XXXX",
    address       = "Southampton, United Kingdom"
}
@book {Lifante:Fundamentals,
    title = "Integrated Photonics: Fundamentals",
    author = "Lifante, Ginés",
    publisher = "J.~Wiley",
    address = "Chichester",
    year = "2003",
    type = "text",
    isbn = "9780470848685"
}
@article{Labadie:First_fringes,
    author = {Labadie, L. and Mart\'{\i}n, G. and Anheier, N. C. and Arezki, B. and Qiao, H. A. and Bernacki, B. and Kern, P.},
    title = {First fringes with an integrated-optics beam combiner at 10},
    DOI= "10.1051/0004-6361/201116727",
    journal = {A\&A},
    year = 2011,
    volume = 531,
    pages = "A48"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=article,prefixnumbers={A-}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=book,prefixnumbers={B-}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=online]

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative is to allow for some "emergency" extra space:

```
\appto{\bibsetup}{\emergencystretch=1em}
```

[image]

Comment: The unbreakable space helped solving the third problem, just like you mentioned, but removing the `[ps2pdf]` changed nothing (so 1st still remains). I can't use pdflatex, as I am heavily operating with `pstricks` and pdflatex makes that very hard. So I'm always going `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` (of course sometimes I'm using `biber` after `latex`).

Comment: @DL6ER In that case, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20768/how-to-allow-line-break-in-a-long-hyperlink-in-a-pdf-compiled-by-latex-dvips-ps2

Comment: Already seen that, but neither using `\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}` nor adding `\usepackage{breakurl}` after `hyperref` solves the first problem.

Comment: @DL6ER Too bad. As I know next to nothing about DVI mode, I suggest you update your question, specifically pointing out the issue my answer didn't solve. That way (and by adding the [tag:dvips] tag), it is more likely to attract a suitable expert.

Comment: Really strange: `latex + dvipdfm` is working as expected, while `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` fails. Hope someone can tell how to fix this.