# How to wrap web address in table?

Tags: tables, longtable, wrap

All of my text in my table wraps except for line 13, which I have copied below.  The website runs off to the side of the page.  I'd like it to wrap the web address.  Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|p{13cm}|}
\caption[]{Disqus IT} \label{DisqusIT} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ Sample }} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13cm}|}{\textbf{Text}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Disqus IT continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ Sample }} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Text}} \\ \hline 
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
  13 I really really really really like to think about this stuff: http://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll\_call\_lists/roll\_call\_vote\_cfm.cfm?congress=113\&session=1\&vote=00032 \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Instead of “escaping” `_` and `&` manually you should take a look at the `\url` macro of the `url`/`hyperref` package. Take a look at another question that discussed this: [Forcing linebreaks in \url](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033)

Comment: In addition to encasing the URL in an `\url{...}` construct, as pointed out by @Qrrbrbirlbel, you should probably also place a `&` between `13` and `I really really ...`.

Answer (score 3):

it makes no sense to have such a long url in a tabular column which doesn't allow a linebreak. USe package `ltablex` then you can use the environment `tabularx` which behaves like a `longtable`. The package is available at 
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ltablex

It has no correct license statement. The reason why it is not on TeXLive and maybe MikTeX, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|p{13cm}|}
\caption{Disqus IT \label{DisqusIT}} \\\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ Sample }} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13cm}|}{\textbf{Text}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Disqus IT continued from previous page}} \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ Sample }} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Text}} \\ \hline 
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

  13 I really like to think about this stuff: \url{http://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll_call_lists/roll_call_vote_cfm.cfm?congress=113&session=1&vote=00032} & 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `ltablex` is included in miktex.