# How to use \url in sloppypar to make url into multi-lines?

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, footnotes, urls

I met a problem about how to make the long link into a multi-lines one.

The following is LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\begin{document}
\section{example}

test \footnote{photo from：Ferroelectrics-Physical-Effects,M.Lallart,2011,InTech, \\ \url{http://www.intechopen.com/books/ferroelectrics-physical-effects/photo-induced-effect-in-quantum-paraelectric-materials-studied-by-transient-birefringence-measuremen} }：

\end{document}
```

I referred to the suggestions of this [Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url/10401)
But I still could not make `\url` work in `sloppypar`.
That means when I delete `\url{content}` only put "content" in `sloppypa`r it will work but I  need `\url` to highlight or distinguish the url link.

How can I realize this?

I use `XeLaTeX`.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The problem have been solved. Thank you @Herbert You really give me a lot of help.

I should change the  \PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} to \usepackage[hyphens]{url} and that will works :
[image]

I guess I have used the wrong code to Pass Option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Werner already mentioned use the `hyphens` option and for the footnote do not use the `sloppypar` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

foo\footnote{%
Toshiro Kohmoto and Yuka Koyama (2011). Photo-induced Effect in Quantum    Paraelectric Materials Studied by Transient Birefringence Measurement, 
Ferroelectrics~--~Physical Effects, Dr. Mickal Lallart (Ed.), ISBN: 978-953-307-453-5, InTech, DOI: 10.5772/17132. Available from:
\url{http://www.intechopen.com/books/ferroelectrics-physical-effects/photo-induced-effect-in-quantum-paraelectric-materials-studied-by-transient-birefringence-measuremen}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I follow your suggestion but it still does not work. the effect is like this :[weibolink](http://weibo.com/1277230715/zy2rX4peu) in my weibo(sorry I could not upload image in tex.stackexchage.com). I use  '\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref} ' and '\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}' to include my url.

Comment: please provide a _complete_ example code in your question.

Comment: give all the code? I am using someone's template to finish my bachelor thesis. Put all these up?

Comment: no, only the code with `hyperref`, `url` and one word and the footnote

Comment: see my answer which shows a _complete_ example

Comment: I chage the content

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: [effect](http://weibo.com/1277230715/zy2CdyL9U) effect like the following but I want to make them the same long and It seems out of the edge in my main thesis paper but here is right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8892/discussion-between-sikisis-and-herbert)

Comment: @sikisis **Note:** As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again. Herbert was referring [complete minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which helps answering people a lot. It is advisable not to post code in comments rather insert in Q which can be noticed as well.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice! @texenthusiast I will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf):

> Package Option: `hyphens`
>   Ordinarily, breaks are not allowed after “`-`” characters because this leads to
>   confusion. (Is the “`-`” part of the address or just a hyphen?)
>   The package option “`[hyphens]`” allows breaks after explicit hyphen characters. The `\url` command will **never ever** hyphenate words.

This is exactly the problem with your URL. Using the `hyphens` package options allows it to break at `-`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
...
```