# URLs in bibliography: LaTeX not breaking line as expected

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, line-breaking, urls

I am trying to include long URLs in a bibliography, but those often overflow into the margin of the document.

I have seen a number of questions about breaking URLs in bibliography, but after trying every solution, I have not found anything that completely solves my problem. There are apparently a number of ways to allow LaTeX to break line at different places in URLs. But in my case, even though LaTeX breaks line at some places, I still get overflow for some URLs.

Here is the code I am using:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{cite}
```

and with these bibliography entries:

```
@misc(webrtc,
    organization={W3C WebRTC Working Group},
    title={WebRTC 1.0: Real-time Communication Between Browsers},
    howpublished={\url{http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webrtc-20120821/}}
)

@misc(android_javascriptinterface,
    organization={Android Open Source project},
    title={Android WebView addJavascriptInterface reference},
    howpublished={\url{http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)}}
)
```

I'm getting this, for example:

[image]

The entry about Android overflows in the border: my column should end where you can read "browsers." on the first line or "http:" on the third line.

Edit: when trying to create a minimal example for my problem, I noticed that this only occurs when using the IEICE template file. You can find it here: http://www.ieice.org/ftp/tex/ieice/LaTeX2e/, but if you do not want to have to extract the archive and locate the correct file, I have put it there also: http://pastebin.com/BKi2cyMQ

Here is my minimal example:

.tex file:

```
\documentclass[paper]{ieice}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{cite}

\title{Test document}
\begin{document}

this\cite{upnp_spec} is a test\cite{android_javascriptinterface}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs_min}

\end{document}
```

and refs_min.bib file:

```
@misc(android_javascriptinterface,
    organization={Android Open Source project},
    title={Android WebView addJavascriptInterface reference},
    howpublished={\url{http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)}}
)

@misc(upnp_spec,
    organization = {UPnP Forum},
    title = {UPnP Device Architecture 1.1},
    howpublished = {\url{http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf}}
)
```

Is there any way I can fix this ?

Comment: These URLs break for me; it's not pretty, but they break.  There must be something you're not telling us.  Please provide a complete [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: @jon Indeed they break as in the screenshot I posted, but my problem is as you said that they are not pretty: they sometimes break "too late", and overflow into the margin. Do you mean that it does not overflow for you ? There might be a difference with the bibliography style

Comment: Yes, they break without sticking into the margin.  As for why we are observing different things, the best solution is to post a minimal example that others can reproduce for themselves.

Comment: @jon Apparently this problem only occurs with the class file I'm using. I added a minimal example; you can see the updated question.

Comment: biblatex has various counters which lets you change the penalties for breaks in various places in an url. E.g. by enlarging biburllcpenalty you can allow latex to break after lowercase letters.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `url` package provides an interesting extra piece of flexibility, via the construct `\Urlmuskip`.  This specifies the spacing around the breakable characters.  By default it is `0mu` however you can set it some glue specification:

```
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu
```

(Unfortunately the example in the `url` manual is wrong. It says `\Urlmuskip=0pt plus 1mu`. Being a mathematical skip expression the only units allowed are `mu`.)

Anyway in your example this gives:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[paper]{ieice}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{cite}

\title{Test document}
\begin{document}

this\cite{upnp_spec} is a test\cite{android_javascriptinterface} \cite{Author:Title}

\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu\relax
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs_min}

\end{document}
```

with an extra entry in your `bib` file.

Other things one might try to help in general include making the bibliography ragged right.  The easiest way to this is just to write `\raggedright` before your `\bibliography` command.
Better ragged right formatting is provided by the `ragged2e` package.  Unfortunately your class defines the `Center` environment that clashes with the `ragged2e`, so in this case you would have to load it as follows:

```
\let\clsCenter\Center\let\clsendCenter\endCenter
\let\Center\undefined\let\endCenter\undefined
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\let\Center\clsCenter
\let\endCenter\clsendCenter
```

You could then issue `\RaggedRight` just before your `\bibliography` command.  If there is text after the bibliography, you can turn on normal formatting again with the `\justifying` command.

Comment: Actually, in some cases, I had to use "\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 2mu" because apparently "1mu" was not enough. But the URL ends up very "stretched" on the line, so the \RaggedRight command is probably also a good option.

Comment: where exactly do i put the "\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu\relax" ? also in the bib file or just in the doc-body?

Comment: You want it to take effect just before the bibliography, so you can place it as I have in the main file before the `\bibliography` command.  It can also be place in the `.bib` file in a `@Preamble`, but that it is not really the correct thing do, the presentation should depend on the formatting document.

Comment: Works like a charm. I am new to LaTeX, so this is absolutely black magic to me.

Comment: I don't like stretched-out URL's.  Andreas's solution below worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 56):

https://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/how-to-break-long-urls-in-bibtex/

```
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
```

Comment: actually, if you have `-` in your url, then just the 2nd line is enough to break it. Or you can pass the option `hyphens` to the `url` package: `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175451/76755)
Can you please include the longer description from your blog, as well? It would make the answer well rounded. Thank you!

Comment: works for me w/o the last line (\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}) and with the last line causes a package clash error. thanks!

Comment: Added `\do_` to the `\def` to get a long URL with lots of underscores to break before going into the right margin.  When I removed the `breaklinks` option and `\usepackage{breakurl}` nothing changed so I left them out.

Answer (score 26):

When using `biblatex`, this can also be achieved with the `block=ragged` option, see §3.1.2.1 in http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf
i.e. `\usepackage[block=ragged]{biblatex}` will do the trick

Comment: This answers the question. Works fine!

Comment: It also has an undesired effect on the rest of the bibliographic entries.

Comment: Your answer is just like a virus, it ruins everything even when I remove it!

Answer (score 8):

```
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
```

Comment: Works for me .. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I tried all of these solutions, but none of them worked.  The thing that finally worked for me was adding the `\sloppy` command before the `\printbibliography`.

```
\begingroup
\sloppy
\printbibliography
\endgroup
```

(Credit for this solution goes to [Suresh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url) and [lurking_quietly](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/ed3r97/url_too_big_not_being_broken_and_shooting_off/))