# Fix URL overfull

Tags: urls

when I break the URL in the bbl file I had to do more than one step and it takes time, but I would like to know a way or a usepackage to break the URL automatically

Comment: Please, add a minimal working example so we can compile it.

Comment: Perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115690/15925 helps

Comment: Biblatex option at [Heiko's answer to "Line breaks of long URLs in bibliography?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134281/3345)