# Line Break in \url in the footnote

Tags: line-breaking, footnotes, urls

There are many Posts about this Topic

[URL linebreak in footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23394/url-linebreak-in-footnote)

[Line breaking of URLs at "-"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175399/line-breaking-of-urls-at)

I tried it by myself but it doesn't work oon my Tex-File.

I added this in my Code for the url-Style. Could this be the reason why it doesn't work?

```
\DeclareUrlCommand{\url}{%
\def\UrlFont{\color{blue}\normalfont}%      Adding a little color 
\def\UrlLeft##1\UrlRight{\underline{##1}}%  Underlining the url
}
```

But I see no reason, why it doesn't work.

Thanks for help, mayby you guys have an idea.

**Edit:**

Removing the Underline worked so far, but now the lines are indented.
The first line moved to the right up to the line break. After the Line break the footnote is flush left again.

Comment: Do **not** underline the url. Underlined text can not break the line ...

Comment: Worked so far, but now there is an other problem.

Answer (score 1):

My Problem is solved with `\raggedright` and removing the underline.
Thanks for the Help.