# Problem with IEEEtran for LaTeX Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, two-column, ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I download latex bibliography style file from [here](http://www.ieee.org/documents/IEEEtranBST1.tar.gz).

Sample Code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,epsfig,latexsym,graphicx,bm,multirow}
\usepackage[left = .56in, top=.75in,right=.56in,bottom=0.8in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEE}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that references of one column are move to other column and some moves out of page's margin. Example shown in below fig:

[image]

[image]

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: sometime it causes problems on direct copy-pasting or connected url is long

Comment: Is there any way to automatically long connected url move to next line instead of moving to next column/ page margin?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115820/66787