# Bibliography - Spaces between words when using url

Tags: bibtex, hyphenation, urls

As can be seen below, I am trying to figure out how to remove big spaces in the BibTeX based bibliography when URLs are used. I have already checked similar questions on tex.stackexchange but to no avail.

The below example also shows that this issue is evidently caused by the associated URL.

Can anyone provide me with an easy fix for this problem?

### Minimal working example:

Document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\cite{McL10a}
\cite{McL10b}

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\end{document}
```

.BibTeX-File:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Electronic{McL10a,
  author    = {G. Harry McLaughlin},
  year      = {2010},
  title     = {SMOG - Simple Measure of Gobbledygook},
  url       = {https://web.archive.org/web/20100415194430/http://webpages.charter.net/ghal/SMOG.htm},
  timestamp = {2010-04-15},
}

@Electronic{McL10b,
  author    = {G. Harry McLaughlin},
  year      = {2010},
  title     = {SMOG - Simple Measure of Gobbledygook},
  timestamp = {2010-04-15},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

#### Output:

[image]

Edit1:
@davidpurton - Using \Urlmuskip=0mu plus 4mu fixed the spaces in the title, but created new spaces in the url itself.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Have you looked at the manual for the `url` package? If not, I'd recommend starting there. Also, is this really engine-specific i.e. only occurs when you compile with pdfTeX?

Comment: I am currently using TeXworks on Windows, which allows me to use pdfLatex, LuaLatex and XeLatex. Tested all three but the issue still remains.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong tag!

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to clarify things so that the tag didn't confuse people looking at your question.

Comment: Perhaps this post will help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/urls-in-bibliography-latex-not-breaking-line-as-expected/115820#115820

Comment: Yes. I tried \Urlmuskip already. It fixes one problem and created another one. Please see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution here: [Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url)

Adding the following line prior adding the *hyperref* package fixed the issue for me:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
```