# achemso package - URL's breaking across two-column page in bibliography

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, url, achemso

I am using the `achemso` package for a two-column document and my URL's are breaking across the page in the references section. I've tried the following but no success:

- Compiled the document without the `\sloppy` command line and using the normal `achemso` document class description.
- Adding `\usepackage{url}` before `\usepackage{hyperref}`.
- Advice from: [URLs in bibliography: LaTeX not breaking line as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/urls-in-bibliography-latex-not-breaking-line-as-expected)

I've included an MWE, my `.bib` script and image showing the output for reference. I am using TeXstudio 2.12.6 Version 5.9.1.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[journal=chreay,manuscript=review,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}


\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use modern font encodings
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%adds hyperlinks to references in text. [hidelinks] removes blue boxes. 
\usepackage{mciteplus}
%\mciteErrorOnUnknownfalse
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures.
%\sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words.


\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

Text \cite{Mees1952}
Text \cite{Car2018}
Text \cite{Xbox2020}

\bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

**.bib**

```
@article{Mees1952,
author = {Mees, C. E. Kenneth},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/kevin/Documents/Documents/EngD papers/GM02 the scientific literature/BIB TEST - paper2.pdf:pdf},
journal = {Nature},
pages = {972 -- 973},
title = {{{\textcopyright} 1952 Nature Publishing Group}},
volume = {170},
year = {1952}
}
@misc{Car2018,
title = {{Carillion fallout: 'They've literally locked the gate' - BBC News}},
url = {http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-42690807},
urldate = {2018-01-15}
}
@misc{Xbox2020,
title = {{News - Games article}},
url = {https://www.videogameschronicle.com/news/xbox-responds-to-70-next-gen-game-pricing-customers-will-decide/},
urldate = {2018-08-14}
}
```

[image: output]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your case it may help to say `\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}` *before* `\documentclass` (that's necessary because the class loads `url` with different options). This will allow URLs to break at `-` characters (which is usually avoided to avoid the impression that there  is hyphenation going on). Alternatively, you can load `\usepackage{xurl}` anywhere in the preamble to allow line breaks at any place in the URL (can look a bit weird if the URL is broken in the middle of a word, but things probably won't run into the margin).

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, but `hyperref` should usually be last package to be loaded (save for a few exceptions).

Comment: Again unrelated, but the `title` field for `Mees1952` looks extremely fishy. According to https://doi.org/10.1038/170972a0 a more fitting title might be `title = {Secrecy and Industrial Research},` or `title = {Letter to the Editors: Secrecy and Industrial Research},`