# Breaking long URLs on Arxiv.org

Tags: bibtex, hyphenation, urls, arxiv

I have long URLs in my references and I want to submit my paper to arxiv.org.

They use TexLive 2016.

I tried to follow advice at

[Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134191/line-breaks-of-long-urls-in-biblatex-bibliography)

[URLs in bibliography: LaTeX not breaking line as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/urls-in-bibliography-latex-not-breaking-line-as-expected)

to no avail. Interestingly, arxiv.org expects .bbl file, not the .bib file.

I tried to manually insert '\-' hyphenation into the .bbl file but that didn't work.

How can I break long URLs on arxiv.org?

Comment: Did you try with package `xurl`?

Comment: Upon your advice I did but it didn't work.

Comment: Even with a more recent distribution?

Comment: I have no jurisdiction over Arxiv's installed TeXLive 2016 distribution. My question is specific to that, they expect me to submit my paper in source form.

Comment: Could you post a minimal (yet complete) code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I could, but using Arxiv's TeXLive 2016 pdflatex requires registration that defies the minimality requirement. And, I have found a working combination of LaTeX packages and their options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At last

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
```

did the trick.

Comment: I didn't need the first line, which gave me an error.

Comment: `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` produced an 'option clash' error for me. The other answer below worked, though.

Answer (score 4):

After *a lot* of experimenting I found that the following works:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
```

Packages must be in this order. The `biblatex` might not be necessary, but I suppose you are using it anyway.

---

The problem seems to come up from [here](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#nohypertex) and Overleaf has a [relevant lemma](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/LaTeX_checklist_for_arXiv_submissions#Are_you_using_the_hyperref_package.3F). Although these links might provide little insight as to *why* links can't break on arXiv, the reason has to do with how their `HyperTeX` is setup to work.

Comment: This also worked for me on arXiv, thanks.

Comment: this is the one that finally worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as Gergely's but without the hyphen option for url

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX! Please explain, why this a better solution!