# Spaces between text in biblography (natbib)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

Im trying to format på references using natbib, but somehow i always get big ugly looking gaps in my references. Any solutions to this? I have tried the version which i use "howpublished" and the "note".

```
@misc{trafikverket_2018,
author =    {{Trafikverket}},
title =     {{Granskningshandling} {E6.21} {Lundbyleden} delen {Brantingsmotet}–{Ringömotet}},
year =      {2018},
note =      {\url{https://www.trafikverket.se/contentassets/6e09cdddd92c4b7c84bbe584ff72b18d/1_plan_och_milljobeskrivning.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3BepAcid8YwBbAlk_MwWmverrtMrXRMW7JzFC1NHj2QwRlWwJCQ0hOAHY} {Hämtad den 9/2 - 2021}
}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Referenser.bib}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/urls-in-bibliography-latex-not-breaking-line-as-expected

Comment: URLs are hard to break (see Johannes_B's link above), but depending on your document language foreign words are also hard to break (if your document language is Swedish, you'd expect hyphenation to work for Swedish words, but names and proper nouns could still be an issue).

Comment: Note that your URL can be slightly shortened to `https://www.trafikverket.se/contentassets/6e09cdddd92c4b7c84bbe584ff72b18d/1_plan_och_milljobeskrivning.pdf` This might help a tiny bit.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` with `\usepackage{xurl}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you replace `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` with `\usepackage{xurl}`. That way, line breaks can occur *anywhere* in URL strings rather than just at hyphenation characters.

I would also break up the `note` field into two separate fields, with the URL string moving to a newly-created `howpublished` field.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Referenser.bib}
@misc{trafikverket_2018,
   author =    {Trafikverket},
   title =     {{Granskningshandling} {E6.21} {Lundbyleden} delen {Brantingsmotet}–{Ringömotet}},
   year =      {2018},
   howpublished = {\url{https://www.trafikverket.se/contentassets/6e09cdddd92c4b7c84bbe584ff72b18d/1_plan_och_milljobeskrivning.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3BepAcid8YwBbAlk_MwWmverrtMrXRMW7JzFC1NHj2QwRlWwJCQ0hOAHY}},
   note =      {Hämtad den 9/2 - 2021}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{xurl} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\cite{trafikverket_2018}
\bibliography{Referenser}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, and please do give consideration to @moewe's suggestion to simplify and shorten the URL string by omitting the `?fbclid=IwAR3BepAcid8YwBbAlk_MwWmverrtMrXRMW7JzFC1NHj2QwRlWwJCQ0hOAHY` substring.

Comment: Thank u! This worked perfectly, looks much nicer with this package. And yes i trimed the url to, thanks @moeve for noticing that