# How can I break a very long URL in the reference?

Tags: biblatex, biber, urls

I have tried some solutions proposed by others ([URLs in bibliography: LaTeX not breaking line as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/urls-in-bibliography-latex-not-breaking-line-as-expected)), but in vain. The long URL still goes into the margin. How can I break a very long URL in the reference? Thanks!

[image]

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex

% !BIB program = biber

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[
    backend        = biber,
    style          = apa,
    doi            = false,
    url            = true,
    isbn           = false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Thesis.bib}

\begin{document}

Cite this article: \parencite{OFFICEFORNATIONALSTATISTICS_MiddleSuperOutput_2018}.

\printbibliography[title = References]

\end{document}
```

Thesis.bib

```
@online{OFFICEFORNATIONALSTATISTICS_MiddleSuperOutput_2018,
  title = {Middle {{Super Output Area Population Estimates}} (Supporting {{Information}})},
  author = {{Office for National Statistics}},
  date = {2018},
  url = {https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/middlesuperoutputareamidyearpopulationestimates}
}
```

Comment: Have you loaded the `xurl` package?

Comment: Thanks you! xurl really works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [xurl](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xurl) package builds on  the `url` package and allows line breaks in arbitrary positions in the URL string.

[image]

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !BIB program = biber

\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Thesis.bib}
@online{ONS_MiddleSuperOutput_2018,
  title  = {{Middle Super Output Area Population Estimates (Supporting Information)}},
  author = {{Office for National Statistics}},
  date   = {2018},
  url    = {https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/middlesuperoutputareamidyearpopulationestimates}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style = apa, url = true, 
            doi = false, isbn = false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{Thesis.bib}

\usepackage{xurl} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\noindent \parencite{ONS_MiddleSuperOutput_2018}.
\printbibliography[title = References]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you! xurl really works!

Comment: Always my best regards from at this moment the sicilian hospital