How to Align a Long URL within a Bibliography Entry Using BibLaTeX in Nature Style
I'm currently working on a bibliography using the BibLaTeX package in LaTeX with the nature citation style. My bibliography contains an entry with a long URL, and I'm having trouble formatting it so that the entire entry remains aligned correctly. Specifically, the URL in my ninth reference overflows to the next line, disrupting the uniformity of the indentation in my bibliography.Moreover, When I tried using \break command on the bibfile, the link stops working as well.
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
defernumbers=true,
style=nature,
url=true,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{hangparas}{.25in}{1}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Sitography},type=online,resetnumbers=true]
\end{hangparas}
the specific entry in my .bib file that’s causing the issue:
@online{hufbauer2000targeted,
title        = {Targeted sanctions: A policy alternative},
author       = {Hufbauer, Gary C and Oegg, Barbara},
year         = {2000},
url          ={https://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle=hein.journals/geojintl32&div=9&g_sent=1&casa_token=V3aP_TNizJcAAAAA:U3vRHZvQH99bilccnxZ1TgT8btXaY2q13CS0bdKWM0qg4tByNasQuD3oOGdpN8a5tqVkw_urgA&collection=journals},
}
As you can see in the screenshot attached (a sample of my bibliography), the URL is breaking awkwardly, and the indentation is not consistent with the rest of the entries.
What I've Tried:
Adjusting the margins using \setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.0pt}.
Tweaking the width of the hanging indentation using \begin{hangparas}{.25in}{1}.
Neither approach has worked as expected. The URL still doesn’t wrap properly, and the text does not maintain a uniform indentation.


The URL in question contains too much material that is unbreakable with the default settings. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/623387/35864. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864 discusses this issue and related ones in more detail and offers several solutions https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864.
