# How to rigidly chop long lines in plain TeX

Tags: line-breaking, urls, plain-tex

I am using plain TeX and want to typeset an appendix that contains several hundred URLs.  When a URL goes past the right margin, I would like TeX to stop printing (i.e. not carry into the margin, not print a warning black rectangle) and then pick up the rest of the URL on a new (non-indented) line where it left off.

Something like this, where 1, 2, 3 are akin to footnote numbers:

```
1: http://www.aaa.com/rem
ainder 2: http://www.bbb.
com/remainder_again  3: h
ttp://www.ccc.com/ending
```

Is this possible?

I am using a Python script to generate the .tex files, so, if worst comes to worst, I can have Python estimate the content of each line.  Unfortunately, I am not using a mono-spaced font, so that could turn pretty ugly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `url` package. And welcome to TeX.SX!!

Comment: @Sean: Please note the OP is using [tag:plain-tex].

Comment: @morbusg I wonder if you have a 'true plain' solution: I've taken the easy way out and used `url` with `miniltx` :-)

Comment: Are the URL's to be clickable?

Comment: URLs are not to be clickable.  This is for printing on paper!  :-)

Comment: @morbusg I feel silly; my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're generating the TeX code with Python, one option is to separate every character with `\hskip0pt`. For example:

```
\def\a{a\hskip0pt}
\def\b{\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a}
\def\c{\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b}
\def\d{\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c}

\d
```

Comment: This could really mess up kerning/typography, but then again it's a URL. (In case you care.)

Comment: This worked!  But there are two caveats: (1) I had escaped characters like & to {\&} in my URLs, but of course I had to unescape and then re-escape them for this solution to work, and (2) Putting `\hskip0pt` between *every* character exceeded TeX's memory capacity (I have a LOT of URLs!) but reducing it to every fifth character worked pretty well.  There are a few overfull boxes, but I can live with that.

Comment: After adding the `tolerance` and `emergencystretch` from @Joseph Wright's answer, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The LaTeX `url` package can be used with plain TeX using `miniltx` (or you could copy the minimal code, of course). For example

```
\input miniltx %
\input url.sty %
\urlstyle{rm}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}
\hsize 4.4cm %
\noindent
1.~\url{http://www.aaa.com/remainder}
2.~\url{http://www.bbb.com/remainder_again}
3.~\url{http://www.ccc.com/ending}
\bye
```

will give you breaking at any character using the method suggested in the `url` manual and [Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url/10401). Things are dependent on line-width: with very few 'normal' spaces in the example above avoiding overfull boxes is hard, and the equivalent of LaTeX's `\sloppy` may also be required, *e.g.*

```
\tolerance 9999 %
\emergencystretch 3em %
```

I'm assuming we have to allow breaks *everywhere*: that is normally not such a great plan if it can be avoided.

To understand what is happening, notice that `url` (ab)uses math mode to allow breaking 'anywhere', making any breakable URL character into a mathbin character inside the URL.

Comment: One could also use [`eplain`](http://tug.org/eplain/) to load `url`: `\input eplain \beginpackages \usepackage{url} \endpackages \enablehyperlinks \url{http://foo/bar} \bye` (from the eplain manual).

Comment: Yields a "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry" error.  I thought the problem might be too many possible breakpoints (see comment to @ChrisS's answer), but even when I reduce the number of "do" macros to three, the error persists.

Comment: It appears that something to do with the `\url` macro could be at fault.  This page has lots of examples of that causing the same error:  http://handyfloss.wordpress.com/2006/11/30/tex-capacity-exceeded-error/

Comment: @IronPillow Do you get that with exactly what I put as an example?

Comment: (1) The exact sample above runs error-free.  (2) If I add an extra line above the `\bye` that inputs my file of 8024 `\url` macros, it runs error-free.  (3) If I repeat (2) but delete the line `\hsize 4.4cm` then it yields a "capacity exceeded" error.  (4) If I split the 8024 URLs into 4 paragraphs, then (3) runs without error.

Comment: Curiously, when I remove the period after each of the numbers 1,2,3: (a) the black rectangles are printed at the end of every line and (b) the right margin is ragged.

Comment: Using the suggested `tolerance` and `emergencystretch` solves the black-rectangle and ragged-margin problems.