# url break in biblatex versus url break in \url

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I have code. In this code the url break in \printbibliography is not working. The url break in \url is working.
Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
    @misc
    {
        mybibkey,
        url = {http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementarladungasdlfkjasalsdkfjhalskdjdfhjalksdjdfhjalksjdfhj}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro\UrlBreaks
    {%
        \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
        \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
        \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\&\do\1\do\2\do\3%
        \do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\0\do\/\do\.%
    }
    \g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials
    {%
        \do\/{\mbox{\UrlFont/}\hskip 0pt plus 2pt}%
    }
\makeatother
%\usepackage{breakurl}

\begin{document}

    See~\cite{mybibkey}.

    \printbibliography
    \noindent\url{http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementarladungasdlfkjasalsdkfjhalskdjdfhjalksdjdfhjalksjdfhj}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: outputOfCode]

I get a warning from writeLaTeX if I uncomment \usepackage{breakurl}:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breakurl/breakurl.sty:
Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.
```

How to solve? There are many google entries and stack exchange entries about this issue but nothing is working.

Comment: biblatex has its own "url breaking" penalties. Use e.g. `\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{1}` to allow breaks after lowercases. See the documentation for others. `breakurl` is sense- and useless with pdflatex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer I can post now the answer that I searched for. The three lines before `\begin{document}` are the key lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
    @misc
    {
        mybibkey,
        url = {http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementarladungasdlfkjasalsdkfjhalskdjdfhjalksdjdfhjalksjdfhj}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro\UrlBreaks
    {%
        \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
        \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
        \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\&\do\1\do\2\do\3%
        \do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\0\do\/\do\.%
    }
    \g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials
    {%
        \do\/{\mbox{\UrlFont/}\hskip 0pt plus 10pt}%
    }
\makeatother
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{1}  %break URL after uppercase character
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{1} %break URL after number
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{1}  %break URL after lowercase character

\begin{document}

    See~\cite{mybibkey}.

    \printbibliography
    \noindent\url{http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementarladungasdlfkjasalsdkfjhalskdjdfhjalksdjdfhjalksjdfhj}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: outputOfCode]