# How do I shrink my URL font size in bibliography's or references sections?

Tags: fontsize, urls

I have a document (an `article`) which I am writing and it includes a references section at the end in the form of a bibliography. I am using the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and setting the bibliography manually via

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{..}

  \bibitem{..}

  ...
\end{thebibliography}
```

In the current font size (11, which doesn't seem unreasonable) the URL's I am inserting often run over several lines. I would like to shrink them to either size 10 or size 9 point font.

How can I do this?

Is there a `\fontsize{text here}` command or something like that which I can use?

Comment: If you're using `\url` to set the URL, then you should follow the instructions listed in [Forcing linebreaks in `\url`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/5764). It's better to maintain the same font size rather than switching to something smaller/different from the main text. If you really have to, you can use font switches/declarations, like `{\small\ttfamily <url>}`. See [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764) for a list of font switches.

Comment: @Werner No I don't want line breaks in the URL, LaTeX is doing those just fine for me automatically - what I want to do it shrink the font, either 1 or 2 pt down.

Comment: You can also issue `\sloppy` inside your `thebibliography` environment and then contain the URL inside `\mbox{<url>}`. For stepping down one point, use `\small`. See [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)

Comment: @Werner what does `\sloppy` do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27609/discussion-between-werner-and-user3728501).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My suggestion would be against adjusting font sizes in favour of consistency. If line-breaking is a problem, consider following the suggestions in [Forcing linebreaks in `\url`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/5764).

However, you can change the font size of a URL *locally* using

```
... {\small \url{<URL>}} ...
```

For making a *global* change to font sizes, use

```
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\ttfamily\small}
```

in your preamble.

Depending on the size of `\normalsize`, `\small` will provide the next step smaller text. For a list of the font sizes associated with these font switches/declarations, see [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)

Comment: For anyone reading the above comments - I was getting the error when putting \small inside of \url, but reversing the ordering as Werner suggested fixed the issue.