# \RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}, at

Tags: urls

I need to break a url at both '_' and '-':

http://www.domain.org/word/word-word_(word-word)/.

Thanks to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url),  by using `\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}` and `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`, I get line break at '-', but it does not seem to work at '_'.
Your advise is welcome.

UPDATE

```
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\makeatletter
\def\do@url@hyp{\do\-\do\_}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\url{http://www.dom.it/aaaa/word-word\_word-word\_word-word\_word-word\_word-word\_word-word\_word-word------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------(xyz)}

\url{http://www.dom.it/aaaa/word-word\_word-word\_word-word/word-word\_word-word\_word-word\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_(xyz)}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

So, it seems that it works with '_', and it does not with many '-'.
Your comment is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The `hyphens` option executes

```
\def\do@url@hyp{\do\-}
```

and you just want to add `\do\_` to this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\def\do@url@hyp{\do\-\do\_}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0pt}
\hspace{0pt}\url|http://www.domain.org/word/word-word_(word-word)/|
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The `minipage` is just to force as much splitting as possible.

[image]

Comment: @@egreg indeed it works, thanks. However, see my edit, I appreciate your comment.

Comment: @mario `\_` is different from `_`; if you try with `__`, you'll see that also this is only split after the last underscore, just like `--`.

Comment: @@egreg  yes, of course; why?

Comment: @mario I believe it's a precise choice by the author of the package, in order to avoid ambiguities.