# fontspec changes indentation of biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, xetex, koma-script, fontspec

**MWE:**

test.tex:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[paper=A4,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{resources.bib}
\begin{document}    
\cite{Test.2018}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

resources.bib:

```
@misc{Test.2018,
    author = {{Test}},
    year = {2018},
    title = {Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.}
}
```

Adding `\usepackage{fontspec}` decreases the indentation of the biblatex entries in the bibliography, removing it increases it again. Why?

I came across this problem after trying to break a long url in the bibliography of an article. The decreased indentation changes the breakpoint. Furthermore it makes the url overflow by one stubborn character even though I set biburllcpenalty and biburlucpenalty accordingly. Without using fontspec there is no overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably someone who knows KOMA-Script better may be able to give a more precise answer. But, as far as I was able to understand, this behavior hangs on how `scrartcl` class handles `\parindent` which is, in turn, used by biblatex to set the bibliography hanging indent.

biblatex uses the length `\bibhang` on the bibenvironment of the `authoryear` style. And it is set in `biblatex.def` with:

```
\setlength{\bibhang}{\ifnumequal{\parindent}{0}{1em}{\parindent}}
```

Which will set `\bibhang` to `\parindent` but default `\bibhang` to 1em if `\parindent` is 0 for some reason, which is not the case here (that is `\parindent` is not 0, so `\bibhang` actually receives `\parindent`).

Now if we build the document below with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\typeout{\the\parindent}

\begin{document}

\the\parindent

\end{document}
```

The PDF will print "12.0pt", but we will find "20.0pt" in the log.

This means that, for some reason, `\parindent` is 20pt in the preamble, and 12pt in the document. biblatex sets `\bibhang` in the preamble, thus, in the absence of other intervening packages, takes the value of 20pt.

Now, if we add `fontspec` to the document:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\typeout{\the\parindent}

\begin{document}

\the\parindent

\end{document}
```

We will find "12pt" in both the document and the log. So, if `biblatex` is called after `fontspec`, it will receive now the value of 12pt.

This doesn't really mean that `fontspec` is responsible for this setting on it's own. As far as I grasp, it is more likely bringing some KOMA hook anticipating the setting which would otherwise come "at begin document". For example, if we substitute the call to `fontspec` with KOMA's `\recalctypearea`, we get the same result: 12pt in both the document and the log.

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\recalctypearea

\typeout{\the\parindent}

\begin{document}

\the\parindent

\end{document}
```

This explains why, in `scrartcl` class, if you load `biblatex` after `fontspec` you get different `\bibhang`s. But I cannot really explain why `\parindent` works the way it does in `scrartcl`.

Still, as you probably want `fontspec` anyway in your document, this discussion is more of a curiosity. You woudn't want to remove `fontspec` just because, by sheer chance (yes, a change in `\bibhang` may trigger an overfull hbox in you url) it allows for a better line break in a single bib entry. So you'll have to look for some other form to break your entry's url (there are several answers in this site on this subject).

Comment: +1. A very thorough analysis!

Comment: If biblatex uses parindent in the preamble it is a biblatex error. Packages shouldn't expect font dependant values to be correct there.

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/848

Comment: @UlrikeFischer See link above. Is there any way to delay the expansion here? I don't want to set the `\bibhang` in the preamble to avoid having to have the user go through `\AtBeginDocument` hooks.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Can you point me to "some other form" to break my entry's url? The only clean and valid option for biblatex seems to be biburllcpenalty and the likes.

Comment: @YoungUn Some, in no particular order, and non exhaustive: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372003/105447 ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115690/105447 ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15653/105447 ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78093/105447 . If those, or other you may find, do not help, I suggest you ask a new question, then adding the example you later added. Here I focused on your question, as initially posed.