# Natbib Citation

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I wanted to get the title for each reference in italics, though apart from changing the style of references used (causes a lot of errors) I'm not sure of any other method. Also the first link of the first reference seems to extend beyond the margin (no other references with links shows the same behaviour). Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[breaklinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@misc{ForwardReverseBias,
    title={Understanding the difference between P and N type semiconductors},
    author = {Power-and-beyond},
    howpublished={\url{https://www.power-and-beyond.com/understanding-the-difference-between-n-and-p-type-semiconductors-a-905805/}},
    year={2012}
}

@misc{Conductivity,
    title={Introduction to Inorganic Chemistry, Electronic Properties of Materials, Superconductors and Semiconductors},
    author={LibreTexts},
    howpublished={\url{https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introduction_to_Inorganic_Chemistry/10%3A_Electronic_Properties_of_Materials_-_Superconductors_and_Semiconductors/10.05%3A_Semiconductors-_Band_Gaps_Colors_Conductivity_and_Doping
    }}
}

@misc{Semiconductor,
    title={Semiconductor - Wikipedia},
    author={Wikipedia},
    howpublished = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor
    }}
}
\end{filecontents}

\title{A}
\author{Generic Account}
\date{August 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

a\cite{ForwardReverseBias} a\cite{Semiconductor} b\cite{Conductivity}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references.bib}


\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When including .bib files, use filecontents please so that the code is all in one file as it is a lot easier to copy and paste. I do not know how to change the natbib format, hopefully someone else does, but to fix the first url extending beyond the margin put `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` before hyperref and it forces the line break, courtesy of Heiko: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372007/245306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A preliminary observation: Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, I would strongly recommend employing the `unsrtnat` rather than the older `unsrt` bibliography style.

To instruct the `unsrtnat` bibliography style file to render the contents of `title` fields in italics, I suggestion you proceed as follows.

- Find the file `unsrtnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. May a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `unsrtnat-ital.bst`.
- Open the file `unsrtnat-ital.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use to edit tex files will do fine.
- In the `.bst` file, search for the function called `format.title`. In my copy of the file, the format.title function starts on line 299.
- In this function, find the following line:

  ```
      { title "t" change.case$ }
  ```

  Change this line to:

  ```
      { title "t" change.case$ emphasize }
  ```
- Save the file `unsrtnat-ital.bst` either in the directory that houses the main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. (If you have no idea what the preceding sentence means, just choose the first options...)
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-ital}
  ```

  and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@misc{ForwardReverseBias,
    title={Understanding the difference between n- and p-type semiconductors},
    author = {Power-and-beyond},
    url={https://www.power-and-beyond.com/understanding-the-difference-between-n-and-p-type-semiconductors-a-905805/},
    year={2012}
}
@misc{Conductivity,
    title={Introduction to Inorganic Chemistry, Electronic Properties of Materials, Superconductors and Semiconductors},
    author={LibreTexts},
    url={https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introduction_to_Inorganic_Chemistry/10%3A_Electronic_Properties_of_Materials_-_Superconductors_and_Semiconductors/10.05%3A_Semiconductors-_Band_Gaps_Colors_Conductivity_and_Doping}
}
@misc{Semiconductor,
    title={Semiconductor},
    author={Wikipedia},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbers,compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-ital}
\usepackage{xurl} % <-- load 'xurl', not 'url', package
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{ForwardReverseBias,Conductivity,Semiconductor}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative response! I've got it set up now, though since I'm using overleaf, the italics part may have to be skipped

Comment: @GenericAccount - If you can't find `unsrtnat.bst` on Overleaf, you may always get it from the CTAN in the directory https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib.

Comment: Yup thanks for the link. I hope you don't mind me asking one last thing: is there a way to keep the capital letters in the titles?

Comment: @GenericAccount - Just enclose the contents of the `title` field in a second set of curly braces if you don't want BibTeX to apply so-called "sentence style" to any of the words in the title.