# How to add a long legend in a figure while allowing line-breaking, with or without hyphenation

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, legend

Hello I encountered a problem with breaking lines using package - `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`.

It works perfectly in every situation expect this one where I use it in `\textsuperscript{}`. Unfortunately `\textsuperscript{}` was the only way found to include source with smaller font size below a picture.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.64]{example-image-a}
    \textsuperscript{Source and some text to reproduce the problem of non-hyphenation: \url{http://google.com/}}
    \caption{Schema}
    \label{abc}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `{\footnotesize Source: \url{http://google.com/}\par}`.

Comment: Henri's approach is reasonable. But you could also try the `sloppypar` environment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40521/35642

Comment: Please try giving a real minimum working example at your questions. I edited just instead of accepting an edit with no changes...

Comment: @Henri Menke Yea!! The size of the font is a bit bigger but still smaller than caption which resolves my problem. I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Sorry @koleygr for that. I will try reminding myself that while asking new question

Comment: No problem, I had it already created and found a review to accept but there where no real changes to your code... So I just added some lines. You don't have to try to remember... You have to get in the place of the one who try to help you when posting any question in any forum... It is sure that if he can easily reproduce your problem, you have more possibilities to make him try to solve... ... Just write what you would like to see to make you help... Wait some time (days) for @HenriMenke to make his comment a real answer and if he will not, please write and accept the answer you already have.

Comment: @koleygr -- Excellent MWE! :-)

Comment: @thiagowfx - `\sloppy` (or `\sloppypar`) won't help here, as the argument of a `\textsuperscript` directive doesn't get line-broken.

Answer (score 2):

> `\textsuperscript{}` was the only way found to include source with smaller font size

Nothing in the argument of a `\textsuperscript` -- or, for that matter, `\textsubscript` -- directive is ever line-broken. And this observation pertains not just to URL strings that may occur in the argument of `\textsuperscript`.

Try a switch such as `\footnotesize` (20% linear reduction of font size) or `\scriptsize` (30% linear reduction) instead. Don't use `\tiny` unless you're prepared to distribute a magnifying glass with each copy of your document...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% just for this example:
\usepackage[textwidth=10cm,showframe,nomarginpar]{geometry} 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.64]{example-image-a}

    {\scriptsize Source and some text to reproduce the problem 
     of non-hyphenation: \url{http://google.com/}\par}

    versus % this is typeset at "\normalsize"

    \textsuperscript{Source and some text to reproduce the problem 
     of non-hyphenation: \url{http://google.com/}}

    \caption{Schema} % the caption is also typeset at "\normalsize"
    \label{abc}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```