# Bibtex format URL

Tags: bibliographies, url

my bibtex looks like this:

```
@Misc{CordaWhite,
title        = {{Corda Whitepaper}},
howpublished = {\url{https://docs.corda.net/_static/corda-introductory-whitepaper.pdf}},
note         = {Accessed: 2017-08-28},
}
```

but the created entry looks like this: [image: Entry]

Here is the import:

```
\begin{document}
....
\bibliographystyle{plain}
bibliography{lit/lit}
...
\end{document}
```

How can I remove the excessive white space?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please complete with a small document loading that bib entry?

Comment: Can you please include picture directly in the question and not on some third-party site?

Comment: @samcarter I would love to but I don't know how

Comment: Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official Stack Exchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: Ctrl+G). This ensures that all images will always be accessible and won't expire.

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Please post a *full* [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). The code you have shown so far is not enough to diagnose the problem. We need to know which bibliography package you use (incidentally, you have tagged your question with `biblatex`, but it does not look as though you actually use that package). We also need to know the exact style (`\bibliographystyle{???}`). These two are crucial to the presentation of your bibliography.

Comment: Hey I added the picture and the \bibliographystyle. I tried to changed the bibliographystyle on my own but it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Doe any of the answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/35864 help you? I have removed the `biblatex` tag since you evidently don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

When making questions, please always add a MWE. Often they are self-explanatory of *all the aspects*  of the problem or the solution, as I hope that is the case of the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\cite{CordaWhite}  \verb|\url|  \verb|\href|\par
\cite{CordaWhite1} \verb|\href|\par
\cite{CordaWhite2} \verb|\href| allowing extra hyphens\par
\cite{CordaWhite3} \verb|\href| allowing line breaks without hyphens\par
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}
\lipsum[2] % to show the right margin
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]