# What is the difference between url and xurl?

Tags: best-practices, url

Like I understood adds `xurl` better line breaking to `url`. Right, or is one of it obsolete? When not, what should I use in which case?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: `xurl` loads the `url` package and adds additional breaking points.

Comment: See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407368/101651

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xurl` loads the `url` package and adds some stuff for additional breaking points for all alphanumerical characters and `= / . : * - ~ ' "`

Which one to choose depends on your preferences. If you want the additional breaking points, use the `xurl` package - if not the `url` package.