# Extra spaces appear in footnotes

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I'm working on my thesis now and noticed I get extra spaces in my footnotes, I suppose because of long web links. I've tried to fix this with `url` and `hyperref` packages, it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[left= 3 cm,right= 2.5 cm,top= 2 cm,bottom=2 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother
```

Here is what I get in my footnotes:
[image]

As you see last footnote has a huge space between words and I get same thing on several pages.
I hope somebody can help me!

Comment: The problems is that the URL in footnote 45 can't be nicely broken with the usual URL breaking rules. You could load the `xurl` package, which allows URLs to be broken everywhere and not just at points where it looks nice. That should drastically reduce issues with overfull/undefull boxes, but may lead to some URL breaks that don't look as pretty (words in URLs may be split in the middle without regard for syllables and usual hyphenation points).

Comment: In footnote 42 I would add a space before "(Hrsg.)". Just curious: Do you write your citations manually or do you use a citation package such as `natbib` or `biblatex`?

Comment: The space might be reduced by replacing the typed space by `\hspace{.3em}` with no stretch.  If effective (not tested) this would still result in an "underfull" message, and with luck a short first line.  Not ideal, but better looking.  There's a long discussion about breaking urls in this question: [Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033)

Comment: @moeve thank you! regarding your question, I write my citation manually. Didn't figure it out with pacages yet

Comment: @barbara beeton that helped, thanks!!