# length of URL link is too long and went beyond the margin of the paper

Tags: urls, fit

I wrote the codes for generating references as shown:

```
@incollection{bordes,
title = {Translating Embeddings for Modeling Multi-relational Data},
author = {Bordes, Antoine and Usunier, Nicolas and Garcia-Duran, Alberto and Weston, Jason and Yakhnenko, Oksana},
booktitle = {Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 26},
editor = {C. J. C. Burges and L. Bottou and M. Welling and Z. Ghahramani and K. Q. Weinberger},
pages = {2787--2795},
year = {2013},
publisher = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
url = 
{http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5071-translating-embeddings-for-modeling-multi-relational-data.pdf}
}
```

However, the URL is too long and it went beyond the margin of the paper. I'm wondering if we can restrict the URL? See the following picture:

[image]

Comment: By default URLs are only broken after certain characters (`/.,_` etc., but not `-` to avoid confusion with hyphenation) in your case with narrow text that is a problem. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/35864 for possible ways to improve URL breaking (read all answers, not just the accepted answer).

Comment: Have you tried loading the `xurl` package?