# Fixing hbox overflow by breaking \href?

Tags: line-breaking, typography, urls, href, overflow

Similar to the URL problem: [Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/98645) and [URL latex linebreak](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2640111/5008962)
My links do cause an hbox overflow.

However, I have an `\href` with a local link. Can I force line breaks at any char there, too?

Code:

```
\newcommand*{\linkLocal}[1]{\href{run:./#1}{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\linkLocalName}[2]{\href{run:./#1}{\texttt{#2}}}
```

So how can I force a line-breaking in `\href` similar to the solutions for `url`? I just want to break at all characters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\newcommand*{\linkLocal}[1]{\href{run:./#1}{\url{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\linkLocalName}[2]{\href{run:./#1}{\url{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \linkLocal{very-long-and-strange-name-for_a_program.exe}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

is doing the trick. Or I misunderstood the question?

[image]