# Allow arbitrary linebreaks in href macros

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, urls

I'm trying to have arbitrary line breaks in text created by Hyperref's `\href` macro. Actually, I found a solution for the `\url` macro [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/69595), but I don't know how to extend it to `\href`.

*A bit of context*. I'm preparing a bibliography and I'm trying to get advantage of DOI. My intent is to display DOIs as “doi:**10.000/xxxx.yyyyy.zzzzzz**”, where the boldface text is linked to `http://doi.org/10.000/xxxx.yyyyy.zzzzzz`, and it is typeset by using

```
doi:\href{http://doi.org/10.000/xxxx.yyyyy.zzzzzz}{10.000/xxxx.yyyyy.zzzzzz}
```

I would like that the displayed text (i.e., the DOI code) is allowed to be broken at any place or at least, at dots---hyphens work here as line-breaking points as usual.

I found half a dozen related questions, some of them involving `sloppypar`, but that would not be the best solution (since the rest of the document is justified). Thanks in advance.