# Arabic links which are long and line breaks

Tags: hyperref, arabic

I have url-links which are quite long and might exceed a regular line width.
For "regular" long links with UTF-8 characters I have found the solution with the package `xurl`.

Since the URL characters might include as well Arabic characters I am facing the problem how to line break Arabic typeset text which is within an url?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,british]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[tracking=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10,final]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,bidi=basic]{babel}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback("fntFallback",{
"DejaVu Sans:mode=harf",
"NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf"})}
\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}
[RawFeature={fallback=fntFallback}
,SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}% fonts for small caps
]
\babelprovide[import=ar]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz, Language=Default]{Amiri}
\usepackage{xurl}
\urlstyle{same} 
\usepackage[pdfa, unicode]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks={true},
    urlcolor={blue},
}
\begin{document}
    Al Sumaria News (25/7/2020): Najaf Water" explains the reasons for water scarcity in the
    governorate", 
    {\selectlanguage{arabic}\url{https://www.alsumaria.tv/news/محليات/352690/ماء-النجف-توضح-أسباب-شح-المياه-في-المحافظة}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remark:

1. I'm looking for an automatic solution. Adding manual line breaks wouldn't lead to asking here.
2. I'm using `lualatex 1.17.0`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url

Comment: Since I'm using the package `xurl` I don't find any further clues how to solve this issue.